# The Luhn algorithm for verifying credit card numbers, etc

Tags: code-golf, arithmetic, checksum

#### Challenge

Write the shortest [program or function](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2422/46231) to calculate the [Luhn Algorithm](http://enwp.org/Luhn_algorithm) for verifying (credit card) numbers.

#### Luhn algorithm explained

[From RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers), this algorithm for the purposes of this challenge is specified as such, with the example input of `49927398716`:

```
Reverse the digits, make an array:
    6, 1, 7, 8, 9, 3, 7, 2, 9, 9, 4
Double the numbers in odd indexes:
    6, 2, 7, 16, 9, 6, 7, 4, 9, 18, 4
Sum the digits in each number:
    6, 2, 7, 7, 9, 6, 7, 4, 9, 9, 4
Sum all of the numbers:
    6 + 2 + 7 + 7 + 9 + 6 + 7 + 4 + 9 + 9 + 4 = 70
If the sum modulo 10 is 0, then the number is valid:
    70 % 10 = 0 => valid
```

#### IO Rules

**Input**: A string or number (your choice), in your [language's input/output format of choice](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2447)

**Output**: A [truthy or falsy value](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2190/46231), respectively, indicating whether or not the input is valid according to the test above.

#### Notes / Tips

- Try not to accidentally post your own credit card or account numbers, if you use them to test :)
- If the input is invalid and impossible to process **with the specified algorithm** (i.e, too short to work with), you can do whatever you want, including blow up my computer.
- **However**, the previous bullet does not mean that your language can do whatever it wants with Numbers that are too large for it to handle. If your language isn't capable of handling a test case, then consider taking a string as input.

#### Examples

The following examples were validated with [this Python script](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Luhn_test_of_credit_card_numbers#Python); if you think one is wrong or have a question, just ping @cat.

```
49927398716      True
49927398717      False
1234567812345670 True    
1234567812345678 False
79927398710      False
79927398711      False
79927398712      False
79927398713      True
79927398714      False
79927398715      False
79927398716      False
79927398717      False
79927398718      False
79927398719      False
374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368 True
374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834 False
8 False **
0 True  **
```

** according to the Python implementation, but you may do anything because these are too short to be eligible by a strict adherence to the specification.

---

If any of the above invalidates existing answers (though I believe that should not be possible), then those answers are stil valid. However, **new** answers, in order to be valid, should follow the specification above.

#### Leaderboard

```js
var QUESTION_ID=22,OVERRIDE_USER=73772;function answersUrl(e){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/"+QUESTION_ID+"/answers?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+ANSWER_FILTER}function commentUrl(e,s){return"https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/"+s.join(";")+"/comments?page="+e+"&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter="+COMMENT_FILTER}function getAnswers(){jQuery.ajax({url:answersUrl(answer_page++),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){answers.push.apply(answers,e.items),answers_hash=[],answer_ids=[],e.items.forEach(function(e){e.comments=[];var s=+e.share_link.match(/\d+/);answer_ids.push(s),answers_hash[s]=e}),e.has_more||(more_answers=!1),comment_page=1,getComments()}})}function getComments(){jQuery.ajax({url:commentUrl(comment_page++,answer_ids),method:"get",dataType:"jsonp",crossDomain:!0,success:function(e){e.items.forEach(function(e){e.owner.user_id===OVERRIDE_USER&&answers_hash[e.post_id].comments.push(e)}),e.has_more?getComments():more_answers?getAnswers():process()}})}function getAuthorName(e){return e.owner.display_name}function process(){var e=[];answers.forEach(function(s){var r=s.body;s.comments.forEach(function(e){OVERRIDE_REG.test(e.body)&&(r="<h1>"+e.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG,"")+"</h1>")});var a=r.match(SCORE_REG);a&&e.push({user:getAuthorName(s),size:+a[2],language:a[1],link:s.share_link})}),e.sort(function(e,s){var r=e.size,a=s.size;return r-a});var s={},r=1,a=null,n=1;e.forEach(function(e){e.size!=a&&(n=r),a=e.size,++r;var t=jQuery("#answer-template").html();t=t.replace("{{PLACE}}",n+".").replace("{{NAME}}",e.user).replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",e.language).replace("{{SIZE}}",e.size).replace("{{LINK}}",e.link),t=jQuery(t),jQuery("#answers").append(t);var o=e.language;/<a/.test(o)&&(o=jQuery(o).text()),s[o]=s[o]||{lang:e.language,user:e.user,size:e.size,link:e.link}});var t=[];for(var o in s)s.hasOwnProperty(o)&&t.push(s[o]);t.sort(function(e,s){return e.lang>s.lang?1:e.lang<s.lang?-1:0});for(var c=0;c<t.length;++c){var i=jQuery("#language-template").html(),o=t[c];i=i.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}",o.lang).replace("{{NAME}}",o.user).replace("{{SIZE}}",o.size).replace("{{LINK}}",o.link),i=jQuery(i),jQuery("#languages").append(i)}}var ANSWER_FILTER="!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe",COMMENT_FILTER="!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk",answers=[],answers_hash,answer_ids,answer_page=1,more_answers=!0,comment_page;getAnswers();var SCORE_REG=/<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/,OVERRIDE_REG=/^Override\s*header:\s*/i;
```

```css
body{text-align:left!important}#answer-list,#language-list{padding:10px;width:290px;float:left}table thead{font-weight:700}table td{padding:5px}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b"> <div id="answer-list"> <h2>Leaderboard</h2> <table class="answer-list"> <thead> <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="answers"> </tbody> </table> </div><div id="language-list"> <h2>Winners by Language</h2> <table class="language-list"> <thead> <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr></thead> <tbody id="languages"> </tbody> </table> </div><table style="display: none"> <tbody id="answer-template"> <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table> <table style="display: none"> <tbody id="language-template"> <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr></tbody> </table>
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

### Golfscript - 24 chars

```
-1%{2+0!:0)*109%+}*10%8=
```

Explanation:

1. `-1%` reverses the string
2. `{` begins a block (which we use as a loop). Each character in the strings is pushed as it's ascii value.

   1. `2+` adds 2. (the ascii value of a digit is 48+n, so we have 50+n now and the last digit is n)
   2. `0!:0` inverts the value of 0 and stores it (everything is a variable), so we have 1 on the first iteration, 0 on the second, etc.
   3. `)*` adds one to this value and multiplies it, so we multiply by 2, then 1, then 2, etc.
   4. `109%` is remainder modulo 109. This affects only values 5-9 which have been doubled and reduces them to the correct value.
   5. `+` adds this value to the running sum
3. `}*` ends the block and does a 'fold' operation. First, the first character is pushed (since we have reversed, this is the check digit). Then, alternate pushing and executing the block. Thus, we are using the first character's ascii value as the starting value for the running sum.
4. `10%` takes the remainder modulo 10.
5. `8=` will return 1 if the value is 8. We use this because we did not normalize the first pushed character (the check digit).

One might think that we could use `8-` instead of `2+` to save a character by changing `109%` to `89%`, except then we would need to add a space so the `-` is subtraction (instead of `-0`).

Answer (score 11):

### GolfScript, 44 chars

```
-1%{16%}%2/1,\+{(\.{0=2*.9>9*-+}{;}if+}*10%!
```

---

**Selected commentary**

Interestingly, the first two items below demonstrate three completely different uses of the `%` operator: array selection, map, and mod. Most GolfScript operators are "context-sensitive", giving them hugely divergent behaviours depending on what types the arguments are.

1. `-1%` reverses the string. This is important as the digit pairs are counted from the right.
2. `{16%}%` converts all the ASCII digits into numbers, by modding them with 16.
3. `2/` splits the array into groups of 2.
4. `1,` is a cheap way to do `[0]`.
5. `\+` effectively prepends the 0 to the digits array. It does this by swapping then concatenating.

The 0 is prepended in preparation for the fold that comes in next. Rather than taking an explicit initial value, GolfScript's fold uses the first item in the array as the initial value.

Now, let's look at the actual fold function. This function takes two arguments: the folded value, and the current item on the array (which in this case will be an array of 2 or (uncommonly) 1, because of the `2/` earlier). Let's assume the arguments are `1 [2 3]`.

1. `(\.` splits out the leftmost array element, moves the remaining array to the front, then copies it. Stack now looks like: `1 2 [3] [3]`.
2. The `if` checks if the array is empty (which is the case for the last group when dealing with an odd-sized account number). If so, then no special processing happens (just pop off the empty array).
3. For an even group:

   1. `0=` grabs the first (only, in this case) element of the array. `1 2 3`
   2. `2*` doubles the number. `1 2 6`
   3. `.9>9*-` subtracts 9 from the number if it's greater than 9. Implemented as: copy the number, compare with 9, multiply the result (which is either 0 or 1) with 9, then subtract. `1 2 6`
   4. `+` finally adds that to the first number. `1 8`
4. `+` (after the `if`) adds the result of the `if` to the original value, resulting in the new folded value.

After the folding completes, we simply mod with 10 (`10%`), and negate the result (`!`), so that we return 1 iff the sum is a multiple of 10.

Comment: This seems to return 0 for the example number on wikipedia (49927398716)

Comment: nm. I forgot to use `echo -n`

Comment: @gnibbler: Haha, fail. :-P (Seriously, I got stung by that one too, in my initial testing.)

Comment: A few places to save a few easy characters here. `-1% 2/` can be combined into `-2/`. `1,` can be replaced with `0` (0 is coerced to an array, then `+` is concatenate). `9>9*-` can be replaced with `9>+` (since we're only concerned with the last digit). Also, the checking for odd lengths is a bit long, using `.,2%,\+` is shorter. After doing this, we can also change `{16%}%` and `(\0=` into `{16}/` (inside the loop). Once you've done all that, it'll look something like this: `.,2%,\+-2/0\+{{16%}/2*.9>+++}*10%!`.

Comment: @Nabb: Thanks! I'll incorporate those into my solution, although it looks like you already have one that's kicking serious arse. :-)

Comment: Yep, Nabb kicked ass on this one

Answer (score 11):

### Python, <strike>73</strike> 69 characters

```
def P(x):D=map(int,x);return sum(D+[d-d/5*9for d in D[-2::-2]])%10==0
```

Comment: You can save two more chars by not looping backwards : `D[-2::-2]` -> `D[1::2]` as the order of a sum isn't important :)

Comment: `==0` can be shortened to `<1`

Answer (score 10):

## Python 3, 77 bytes

```
c=lambda a:sum(sum(divmod(int(a[-e-1])<<e%2,10))for e in range(len(a)))%10==0
```

Answer (score 10):

**C# 119 characters:**

```
bool l(string n){return(String.Join("",n.Reverse().Select((x,i)=>(x-48)*(i%2<1?1:2)+"").ToArray()).Sum(x=>x-48))%10<1;}
```

Not *too* bad for a code golf n00b in a statically typed language, I hope.

This can be reduced to **100**:

```
bool l(string n){return String.Join("",n.Reverse().Select((x,i)=>(x-48)*(i%2+1))).Sum(x=>x+2)%10<1;}
```

Comment: It's a good idea, and an interesting approach, but it doesn't appear to work. At least not with my few tests. It looks like the "i" in your first lambda is supposed to be the index of the character in the string. Does that work as it should? If so, why do you reverse the string only to then modify it based on index position? Seems a bit redundant, no?

Comment: I only tested one of my credit cards and a few off by one errors from it TBH. (Using the VS 2008 debugger) The algorithm is supposed to double every second digit starting with the LAST digit.  If I didn't reverse the string, it would be incorrect for strings with odd lengths.

Comment: Turns out I did have the result of `i%2<1?1:2` backwards.  Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

## PHP, 108 bytes

```
<?function v($s,$t=0){for($i=strlen($s);$i>=0;$i--,$c=$s[$i])$t+=$c+$i%2*(($c>4)*-4+$c%5);return!($t % 10);}
```

Answer (score 8):

### Golfscript - 34 chars

```
{15&}%.-2%\);-2%{.+(9%)}%+{+}*10%!
```

Example number from wikipedia page 4992739871

```
{15&}%  does a bitwise and of each ascii digit with 00001111
        now I have a list of digits 
        [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1 6]
.       makes a copy of the list, now I have two identical lists
        [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1 6] [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1 6]
-2%     like [::-2] in python takes every second element in reverse
        [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1 6] [6 7 9 7 9 4]
\       swap the two lists around
        [6 7 9 7 9 4] [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1 6]
);      drop the last digit off the list
        [6 7 9 7 9 4] [4 9 9 2 7 3 9 8 7 1]
-2%     same as before
        [6 7 9 7 9 4] [1 8 3 2 9]
{       for each item in the list ...
.+      ... double it ...
(       ... subtract 1 ...
9%      ... mod 9 ...
)}%     ... add 1 ...
        [6 7 9 7 9 4] [2 7 6 4 9]
+       join the two lists
        [6 7 9 7 9 4 2 7 6 4 9]
{+}*    add the elements up
        70
10%     mod 10
        0
!       invert the result
        1
```

Comment: The `.+(9%)` is very innovative (for me, anyway). I like! +1

Comment: Srsly though, GolfScript needs a partitioning operator, so you don't need to do this "drop end item off and repeat" nonsense. :-)

Comment: @Chris, I learned about that many years ago called "casting out nines". It is a neat way to double check longhand additions and multiplications

Comment: This won't work for a value of 0 being doubled (`0(9%)` is 9 and not 0).

Answer (score 7):

## Haskell, 96 bytes

There must be a better/shorter way, but here's my **Haskell** solution in **96 characters**:

```
l=(==0).(`mod`10).sum.zipWith($)(cycle[id,\x->x`mod`5*2+x`div`5]).reverse.map((+(-48)).fromEnum)
```

Sadly the `digitToInt` function can only be used if you `import Data.Char` first. Otherwise I could get down to 88 characters by replacing `((+(-48)).fromEnum)` with  `digitToInt`.

Answer (score 7):

### Ruby - 85 characters

```
def f s
l=s.size
s.chars.map{|k|(i=k.to_i*((l-=1)%2+1))%10+i/10}.inject(:+)%10==0
end
```

Comment: You probably know about this, but you could do .sum instead of .inject(:+) to save 7 bytes

Answer (score 6):

## D, 144 bytes

```
bool f(S)(S s){int t(C)(C c){return to!int(c)-'0';}int n,v;foreach(i,c;array(retro(s))){v=i&1?t(c)*2:t(c);n+=v>=10?v%10+v/10:v;}return n%10==0;}
```

More legibly:

```
bool f(S)(S s)
{
    int t(C)(C c)
    {
        return to!int(c) - '0';
    }

    int n, v;

    foreach(i, c; array(retro(s)))
    {
        v = i & 1 ? t(c) * 2 : t(c);

        n += v >= 10 ? v % 10 + v / 10 : v;
    }

    return n % 10 == 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6):

### Windows PowerShell, 82

```
filter f{!((''+($_[($_.length)..0]|%{+"$_"*($i++%2+1)})-replace'.','+$&'|iex)%10)}
```

History:

- 2011-02-13 03:08 (84) First attempt.
- 2011-02-13 12:13 (82) I don't need to join, as spaces do not hurt. `+1 + +3` can still be evaluated.

Answer (score 6):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 9 bytes

```
ṚḤÐeDFS⁵ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///hzlkPdyw5PCHVxS34UePWhzt6/x9uf7i7@1HDnJCi0lQg5ZaYUwyk5x7a@qhpTeT//9EmlpZG5saWFuaGZjoKCI65joKhkbGJqZm5BZQ2wBCx0FEwh2swQOYYInOMkDnGyBwTZI4pMscMmWOOzEGx1FJHwdjcxMwU6B4zS5CLIAwQbWZpYmFqbmYJZIEYxmYWJuamQJJ4HRbmQE9aGAMdCdRkEAsA)

### How it works

```
ṚḤÐeDFS⁵ḍ - Main link. Takes an integer n on the left
Ṛ         - Cast n to digits and reverse
  Ðe      - To values at even indices:
 Ḥ        -   Unhalve; Double
    D     - Cast to digits
     F    - Flatten
      S   - Sum
        ḍ - Divisible by:
       ⁵  - 10?
```

Answer (score 5):

### PowerShell 123

```
filter L($x){$l=$x.Length-1;$l..0|%{$d=$x[$_]-48;if($_%2-eq$l%2){$s+=$d}elseif($d-le4){$s+=$d*2}else{$s+=$d*2-9}};!($s%10)}
```

Answer (score 5):

## Q, 63

```
{0=mod[(+/)"I"$(,/)($)($)@["I"$'x;1+2*'(!)(_)((#)x)%2;*;2];10]}
```

usage

```
q){0=mod[(+/)"I"$(,/)($)($)@["I"$'x;1+2*'(!)(_)((#)x)%2;*;2];10]}"79927398711"
0b
q){0=mod[(+/)"I"$(,/)($)($)@["I"$'x;1+2*'(!)(_)((#)x)%2;*;2];10]}"79927398712"
0b
q){0=mod[(+/)"I"$(,/)($)($)@["I"$'x;1+2*'(!)(_)((#)x)%2;*;2];10]}"79927398713"
1b
```

Comment: 47 bytes with `{0=mod[sum"J"$raze($)($)x*#:[x]#1 2]10}"I"$'(|)` a different way to double the odd indices.

Answer (score 5):

## APL, 28 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(codepage))

```
{0=10|+/⍎¨∊⍕¨v×⌽2-2|⍳⍴v←⍎¨⍵}
```

**Exploded view**

```
{                     v←⍎¨⍵}  ⍝ turn the string into a numeric vector of its digits, v
                2-2|⍳⍴v       ⍝ make a vector of the same length, with 2 in every 2nd place
             v×⌽              ⍝ multiply it with v, starting from the right
          ∊⍕¨                 ⍝ turn each component into a string and collect all the digits
      +/⍎¨                    ⍝ turn each digit again into a number and sum them
 0=10|                        ⍝ check whether the sum is a multiple of 10
```

**Examples**

```
      {0=10|+/⍎¨∊⍕¨v×⌽2-2|⍳⍴v←⍎¨⍵} '79927398713'
1
      {0=10|+/⍎¨∊⍕¨v×⌽2-2|⍳⍴v←⍎¨⍵} '123456789'
0
```

Comment: -2: `{0=10|+/⍎¨∊⍕¨⍵×⌽2-2|⍳⍴⍵}⍎¨`

Answer (score 5):

## [x86-16 machine code](https://software.intel.com/sites/default/files/managed/39/c5/325462-sdm-vol-1-2abcd-3abcd.pdf), 27 bytes

Binary:

```
00000000: bb00 0103 f1fd ac2c 30f6 df78 06d0 e0d4  .......,0..x....
00000010: 0a02 dc02 d8e2 ef93 d40a c3              ...........
```

Listing:

```
BB 0100         MOV  BX, 100H           ; running sum (BL) to 0, BH to a positive value
03 F1           ADD  SI, CX             ; start at end of input string
FD              STD                     ; set LODSB direction to decrement
            DIGIT_LOOP: 
AC              LODSB                   ; load next digit into AL, decrement SI
2C 30           SUB  AL, '0'            ; convert ASCII char to binary value 
F6 DF           NEG  BH                 ; flip sign of BH to alternate odd/even index
78 06           JS   IS_EVEN            ; if not odd index, do not double
D0 E0           SHL  AL, 1              ; double the value
D4 0A           AAM                     ; split digits (ex: 18 --> AH = 1, AL = 8) 
02 DC           ADD  BL, AH             ; add tens digit to running sum
            IS_EVEN:
02 D8           ADD  BL, AL             ; add ones digit to running sum 
E2 EF           LOOP DIGIT_LOOP 
93              XCHG AX, BX             ; sum is in BL, move to AL for mod 10 check
D4 0A           AAM                     ; ZF = ( AL % 10 == 0 ) 
C3              RET                     ; return to caller
```

Uses (abuses) x86's BCD-to-binary instruction `AAM` to handle the individual digit splitting and `modulo 10` check.

Callable function, input card num string pointer in `SI`, length in `CX`.  Output: `ZF` if valid.

**Example test program output:**

[image]

### Alternate version, 29 bytes

```
33 DB           XOR  BX, BX             ; running sum (BL) to 0
03 F1           ADD  SI, CX             ; start at end of string
4E              DEC  SI                 ; align for WORD
FD              STD                     ; set LODSB direction to decrement
            DIGIT_LOOP:
AD              LODSW                   ; load next two digits into AH:AL, dec SI by 2
25 0F0F         AND  AX, 0F0FH          ; convert ASCII chars to binary value
02 DC           ADD  BL, AH             ; add ones digit of even index to sum
49              DEC  CX                 ; decrement counter for WORD
74 0A           JZ   DONE               ; if input is odd length, will be 0 at the end
D0 E0           SHL  AL, 1              ; double the value
D4 0A           AAM                     ; split digits (ex: 18 --> AH = 1, AL = 8)
02 DC           ADD  BL, AH             ; add tens digit to sum
02 D8           ADD  BL, AL             ; add ones digit to sum
E2 ED           LOOP DIGIT_LOOP
            DONE:
93              XCHG AX, BX             ; move sum to AL for mod 10 check
D4 0A           AAM                     ; ZF = ( AL % 10 == 0 )
C3              RET                     ; return to caller
```

This version loads two digits at the same time, eliminating the flip/flop branch.  The issue here is having to check for an odd number of digits on the input and discard the value in memory right before the beginning of the string once it reaches the last word.  Obviously not shorter, but perhaps someone clever can golf it more!

Comment: I haven't spent very long staring at this, but... Why do you need to iterate through the string backwards? If you iterated forwards, it seems like you'd get the same result, but be able to shave off those initial 3 bytes (setting `SI` and the direction flag [which you can assume is always clear]).

Comment: @CodyGray IIRC I think it has to do with having an odd number of digits, and the LUHN algorithm expecting you to operate on the last digits first. Maybe I should take another look though...

Comment: Yeah, I realize it's an old answer. The Luhn algorithm was brought up in a chat room earlier, so I was considering it, dreaming of it in x86 asm. I decided to check Code Golf, and sure enough, it was already here. With a pretty solid-looking x86 asm answer. Thus, I immediately set out to nitpick. ;-) We were specifically discussing whether it is necessary to iterate backwards. The reference implementation in pseudocode on Wikipedia doesn't appear to go backwards. Didn't even notice about the missing `ret` though. Would take some effort to clean up, probably more than it's worth.

Comment: @CodyGray my quick reading of the Wiki implementation, it seems to first determine if the number of digits is odd or even (`parity := nDigits modulus 2`) and then checks every time through the loop if that index corresponds to a relative odd or even index (`if i modulus 2 = parity`). Maybe that could be golfed, though I tend to think the 3 bytes to start from the end isn't too bad. Also, it looks like I'm going to have to take a +4 bytes penalty to get this submission up to spec with the rules. I guess I didn't quite understand them when I wrote this one. :)

Comment: @CodyGray I played with the idea of iterating forwards using the Wiki-inspired `if ( originalCx & 1 == currentCx & 1 ) then...`, but got a bit fiddly in ASM and was longer for me. Then I tried loading two bytes at a time (while still going backwards) and got it down to +2 bytes longer than the original. Posted it anyway in case it inspires another idea. Would love to see the answer you "dreamed" up too! :)

Comment: You'd probably also like to read the novels that I dream up while sleeping, too. I'll let you know. :-p In your second submission, could the 3-byte `dec cx` + `jz done` be replaced with a 2-byte `loopz done`?

Comment: @CodyGray so I don't think it's going to be a drop-in change... `loopz` is an AND condition - branch if `cx` non-zero *and* `zf` is 1. So in other words would still need to set `zf` somewhere first. Though, it's an interesting idea to see if it can be refactored to set that flag another way in an operation already being done. Will have to try that later on!

Comment: Oh, right, duh. You just want `loop`, not `loopz`. I was for some reason thinking that `dec` didn't set `zf`, but it's actually `cf` that it doesn't set.

Answer (score 4):

## Perl, <s>46</s> <s>42</s> 41 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Give input on STDIN:

```
luhn.pl <<< 79927398713
```

`luhn.pl`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -p
s%.%$=-=-$&-$&*1.2*/\G(..)+$/%eg;$_=/0$/
```

Comment: Can you please explain how this works? You seem to be decrementing by the match and then also by the match times 1.2 but only in the correct positions. Why 1.2? Shouldn't it be `$=-=-$&-$&*/\G(..)+$/`?

Comment: @msh210: It encodes the effect of the multiplication by 2. `0..4` * 2 gives `0, 2, 4, 6, 8` but `5..9` gives `10,12,14,16,18` which sum to `1 3 5 7 9` which have the same last digits as `11 13 15 17 19` which are the same values as `0..9 * 2.2` if you truncate to integer. The first `$&` already contributes a factor `1`, so a correction by `1.2` is still needed. `$=` can only hold integers and starts with a value that ends on 0 so takes care of the truncating. The negative values are needed since the `/\G/` regex changes any `$&` still on the evaluation stack so they need to be changed

Comment: Oh. Brilliant! And thanks for the explanation.

Answer (score 4):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
RSāÈ>*SOTÖ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yy9OTMpM/f8/KPhI4@EOO61g/5DD0/7/N7G0NDI3trQwNzQDAA)
or as a [Test Suite](https://tio.run/##jc87CgJBDADQPqdYthSF@WTyaXaPILheQMHCykIQFmy28wReaL3XOIOiwcomeYSEJKfzbn885Otl7Ntm1TVtP@bN8JjmW7cY1tv5npcZVQNHFfYEXzP4EDERyzu734IAf7qdsTcOxtEYjZMxGbOx3aUQGSmVI0jrGS/UTIqSmLSoIpIgpxL/HhAuj0lEEHBP)

**Explanation**

```
R             # reverse input
 S            # split to list of digits
  ā           # push range[1 ... len(input)]
   È          # map isEven on each
    >         # increment
     *        # multiply doubling every other item
      SO      # sum digits
        TÖ    # mod 10 == 0
```

Answer (score 4):

## [C (clang)](http://clang.llvm.org/), <s>264</s> <s>212</s> <s>196</s> <s>175</s> 172 bytes

```c
l,x;main(i){char*s;gets(s);int n[i=l=strlen(s)];for(;i--;)n[i]=s[i]-48;for(;(i+=2)<l;n[i]>9?n[i]=n[i]/10+n[i]%10:0)n[i]*=2;for(;l--;)x+=n[l];printf(x%10<1?"True":"False");}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##XY7BCoJAEIbvPUUYwa5mqUlp49atJ@gWHjZdbWBawzUQome3tU51mYHv//5hCr8gqethhrqgR6mmmelKbJbX/eQHEV7@WYu6tmygRQ83iZohfxZX2boGatUZZjig7qb6jIKE1Ulpy3KompYB@j5wG@XC2OHHyRcz9ETEM4Ix2qeHjzGOVRh4456HwS74FF0RfTs0nuo9q1EOd/tVV7Heell4cE7tQzk75yjJKIfDaxjiNI226zTZhps3)

Simply the basic way of programming the algorithm, but all whitespace is removed. All I could say is that there are a bunch of for-loops in this one.

Thanks to ceilingcat for golfing 52 bytes, another 16 bytes, and another 21 bytes, and another 3 bytes.

Comment: [156 bytes](https://tio.run/##XYzBCoJAFEX3fUUYgdNopUk2PUd3fUE7cWFq@uA1hTOCEH27aa1qd@@5h1u4BeWqHhaoCurKah5pU@J93cSzH0R4@WctqnpkAzm9o1IhMsfALUdlI3sWTd7O9QThem/tujLa1gx0ShkQ50yNQU7NDQ4fAzAiUClm0sQiMRtvy83S2x6Ng1z6zMhpW/lfl1wXWM/l9AKPbvzuRzfyEuvcdpV1tE456cpi8BqGQAg/3IlD6O3f "C (clang) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript 1.8: 106 characters

This is an original solution I came up with before I found this post:

```
function(n){return!(n.split('').reverse().reduce(function(p,c,i){return(+c&&((c*(1+i%2)%9)||9))+p},0)%10)}
```

Readable form:

```
function luhnCheck(ccNum) {
    return !(                                  // True if the result is zero.
             ccNum.split('').
               reverse().                      // Iterate over the string from rtl.
               reduce(function(prev, cur, idx) {
                 return prev +                 // Sum the results of each character.
                        (+cur &&               // If the current digit is 0, move on.
                         ((cur * (1 + idx % 2) // Double cur at even indices.
                           % 9) || 9));        // Sum the digits of the result.
               }, 0)
            % 10);                             // Is the sum evenly divisible by 10?
}
```

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 61 bytes

Sum of digits of `2*n` is `2*n` if `n in 0..4`, `2*n-9` if `n in 5..9`. That said, all the sum can be computed in one step.

```js
s=>!([...s].reduceRight((t,d)=>t-d-i++%2*(d>4?d-9:d),i=0)%10)
```

Answer (score 3):

## Powershell, 74 bytes

```powershell
param($s)$s[$s.Length..0]|%{(1+$i++%2)*"$_"}|%{$r+=$_-9*($_-gt9)}
!($r%10)
```

### Explanation

1. for each char of an argument string, in reverse order
2. get a digit of double value of a digit
3. a double value of a digit can not be greater then 18. Therefore, we accumulate a value minus 9 if value > 9
4. return true if the remainder of the division by 10 is 0

### Test script

```powershell
$f = {

param($s)$s[$s.Length..0]|%{(1+$i++%2)*"$_"}|%{$r+=$_-9*($_-gt9)}
!($r%10)

}

@(
    ,("49927398716"      , $True)
    ,("49927398717"      , $False)
    ,("1234567812345670" , $True)
    ,("1234567812345678" , $False)
    ,("79927398710"      , $False)
    ,("79927398711"      , $False)
    ,("79927398712"      , $False)
    ,("79927398713"      , $True)
    ,("79927398714"      , $False)
    ,("79927398715"      , $False)
    ,("79927398716"      , $False)
    ,("79927398717"      , $False)
    ,("79927398718"      , $False)
    ,("79927398719"      , $False)
    ,("374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368" , $True)
    ,("374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834" , $False)
    ,("8" , $False)
    ,("0" , $True)
) | % {
    $s, $expected = $_
    $result = &$f $s
    "$($result-eq$expected): $result : $s"
}
```

### Output

```powershell
True: True : 49927398716
True: False : 49927398717
True: True : 1234567812345670
True: False : 1234567812345678
True: False : 79927398710
True: False : 79927398711
True: False : 79927398712
True: True : 79927398713
True: False : 79927398714
True: False : 79927398715
True: False : 79927398716
True: False : 79927398717
True: False : 79927398718
True: False : 79927398719
True: True : 374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368
True: False : 374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834
True: False : 8
True: True : 0
```

Answer (score 3):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://bitbucket.org/ngn/k), 26 bytes

```
{~10!+//10\(1+2!!#x)*.'|x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lY@7DsIwDEV3voKaoS0VNE8/4FeYy4DUuVKBXw8JIMDqxBLf48TXN5fdeB5TGg7z3Zqq63trTo3tXFVtpna7r6/TLQ11A0HEkRcmi3D8IcpknQ8Rid/VLFsM7aq40GeuPPqSVeQUeUVh4RTVPSoiRaxIitMaPAWMOSVKyfkSpaIEjoSSVREeOVDMJ/wzxJR/zz7AM3PZb6BNDw)

Another k variant, with a major debt to [@streetster's answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/154051/98547).

Comment: `1+2!!#x` -> `1+=\~x`

Comment: i rolled back the above change because ` =\ ` works differently now

Answer (score 3):

## [GolfScript](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/), 31 bytes

```
.,2%0\@{48-..4>+@!:a*++a}/;10%!
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8/PSStOLsosKPn/X0/HSNUgxqHaxEJXT8/ETttB0SpRS1s7sVbf2tBAVfH/f0MjYxNTM3MLKG0AAA)

Golfscript pushes the input as a list of characters to the stack
at the start of the program.

```
.                                Duplicate the top of the stack (input)
 ,2%                             Compute the modulo 2 of the length of the input,
                                 pushed 1/0 on the stack if the number if odd/even
    0                            Push an accumulater var on the stack, set to 0
    
     \                           Flip the even/odd and accumulator order on the stack
      @                          Bring the 3rd entry forward, input to the top

       {                }        Code block...
                         /       Apply the block of code to the elements of the list at
                                 the top of the stack. Each time through the loop, the
                                 next element from the list if pushed to the top of the
                                 stack
        48-                      Subtract "0" from the top of stack (which is a codepoint
                                 for the current digit/character)
           ..                    Duplicate the top of stack (the current digit) twice
             4>+                 If the current digit is >4 add one to the digit
                @                Pull the 3rd entry, the even/odd indicator, to the top
                 !:a             Flip the value and save in variable "a"
                    *            Multiple the top two stack entries, will be "0" or the
                                 value of current digit, with or without "1" more for the
                                 "+10" rule
                     ++          Add the current digit, to the possible "double" and
                                 "even/odd" bump
                       a         Push the flipped even/odd indicated to the top
                          ;      Drop the stop of stack, the even/odd indicator 
                           10%   Find the modulo 10 of the accumulated digits
                              !  Invert the result
```

The only thing on the stack is the answer, which is printed by default

Answer (score 3):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/) + `validators`, 5 bytes

```
luhn?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc/NCsIwDADge58iTyDb2iatHjyKFy/iSTyUOXEw5346h4jPXjsUCZ68JB8hIcnJ5f7ahd12vVnNoekK7@9NV9Ye2hH6oh2KOi96uLmqPLrY2cNCtONDKGszktZQiswk0kwqjWQ@OfktGEHf7oQ5Zc6YJbNi1szITMx8lxWSFOp4BNrpjDemjFYZTWijJkg0inSMfw8Yio8ZqYQRiXjCPlTDuV6GA1xcA7PwAg)

Answer (score 2):

#### Scala: 132

```
def q(x:Int)=x%10+x/10
def c(i:String)={val s=i.reverse
(s(0)-48)==10-(s.tail.sliding(2,2).map(n=>(q((n(0)-48)*2)+n(1)-48)).sum%10)}
```

invocation:

```
c("79927398713")
```

- reverse ("79927398713") = 31789372997
- s(0), s.tail: (3)(1789372997)
- sliding (2,2) = (17 89 37 29 97)
- map (q((n(0)-48*2 + n(1)-48)) => q(('1'-'0')*2)+ '7'-'0')=1*2+7

Answer (score 2):

## Haskell: 97

For some reason [this isn't working for me](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/275/7195), so here is my version

```
l=(\x->(==0)$(`mod`10).sum$zipWith($)(cycle[id,sum.map(read.(:"")).show.(*2)])(map(read.(:""))x))
```

Answer (score 2):

## K4, 35 bytes

```
{~.*|$+/.:',/$x*1+1{y;~x}\|x:|.:'x}
```

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 38 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/APL_(codepage))

```
d←10∘⊥⍣¯1⋄{0=10|+/+/d x×1+~2|⍳⍴x←⌽d ⍵}
```

expects the number as a number, not a string, but that's only because [tryAPL](http://tryapl.com) (understandably) doesn't implement `⍎`

further reducible, i'm sure…

Answer (score 2):

### [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), <s>43</s> 42 bytes

Retina is (much) newer than this challenge.

```
;
r`(.);.
$1$&
\d
$*
1+
$.&
.
$*
$
$._
0$
```

The leading empty line is significant.

Prints `0` for falsy and `1` for truthy results.

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JShHYAoKOwpyYCguKTsuCiQxJCYKXGQKJCoKMSsKJC4mCi4KJCoKJAokLl8KTWAwJAopR2A&input=NDk5MjczOTg3MTYKMTIzNDU2NzgxMjM0NTY3MAo3OTkyNzM5ODcxMwozNzQ2NTIzNDY5NTY3ODIzNDY5NTc4MjM2OTQ4NTc2OTIzNjQ4NTczNjg0NzUzNjgKMAoKNDk5MjczOTg3MTcKMTIzNDU2NzgxMjM0NTY3OAo3OTkyNzM5ODcxMAo3OTkyNzM5ODcxMQo3OTkyNzM5ODcxMgo3OTkyNzM5ODcxNAo3OTkyNzM5ODcxNQo3OTkyNzM5ODcxNgo3OTkyNzM5ODcxNwo3OTkyNzM5ODcxOAo3OTkyNzM5ODcxOQozNzQ2NTIzNDY5NTY3ODIzNDY5NTc4MjM2OTQ4NTc2OTIzNjQ4NTczODc0NTY4MzQKOA) (Slightly modified to run all test cases at once.)

#### Explanation

```
;
```

Insert `;` in every position to separate digits.

```
r`(.);.
$1$&
```

From the `r`ight, we repeatedly match two digits and double the left one. This way we avoid an expensive reversing of the list.

```
\d
$*
```

We match each digit and convert it to that many `1`s (that is, we convert each digit to unary).

```
1+
$.&
```

This matches each unary number and converts it back to decimal by replacing it with its length. Together with the previous stage, this adds the doubled digits.

```
.
$*
```

Again, we match every character and turn it into that many `1`s. That is we convert each digit individually back to unary. This also matches the `;` separators, which are treated as zeros in the conversion, which means they're simply removed. Since all the unary numbers are now squashed together we've automatically added the unary representations of the all digits together.

```
$
$._
```

At the end, we insert the length of the entire string, i.e. the decimal representation of the unary checksum.

```
0$
```

Finally we count the number of matches of this regex, i.e. we check whether the decimal representation ends in `0`, printing `0` or `1` accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 14 bytes

```
DUḤJḤ$¦DS$€S⁵ḍ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/98l9OGOJV5ArHJomUuwyqOmNcGPGrc@3NH7//9/E0tLI3NjSwtzQzMA)

Explanation:

```
D              get digits
 U             reverse array
   JḤ$         for every other index,
  Ḥ   ¦        double the value
          €    for each value,
       D $     get the digits
        S$     and sum them
           S   sum the list
            ⁵ḍ check if it's divisible by 10
```

Comment: Why is this non-competing?

Comment: @mudkip201 Correct me if I'm wrong, but this version of Jelly didn't exist when the question was asked, so it isn't valid for the question.

Comment: Pretty sure there was a meta consensus that said that languages that were made after the challenge aren't 'non-competing' any more

Answer (score 2):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>14</s> 13 bytes

Takes input as an array of digits.

```
ÔxÈ*ÒYu)ìxÃvA
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=1HjIKtJZdSnseMN2QQ==&input=WzQsOSw5LDIsNywzLDksOCw3LDEsNl0KLaE=)

```
ÔxÈ*ÒYu)ìxÃvA     :Implicit input of array
Ô                 :Reverse
 x                :Reduce by addition
  È               :After passing each element at 0-based index Y through the following function
   *              :   Multiply by
    Ò             :     Bitwise increment
     Yu           :     Y modulo 2
       )          :   End multiplication
        ì         :   Convert to digit array
         x        :   Reduce by addition
          Ã       :End function
           v      :Test for divisibility by
            A     :  10
```

Comment: This doesn't reverse the array, so inputs like 24 return the wrong result

Comment: Thanks, @EmbodimentofIgnorance, looks like I made a faulty assumption somewhere along the way. Fixed and saved a byte in the process.

Answer (score 2):

## [Pxem](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Pxem), 0 bytes (content) + 147 bytes (filename).

- Filename (escaped): `.w0.-.i.c\001.+.a\001.+.t.v.m.vQJ.z.v.m.v.c.m.+.c.t.-.m.v.t.v.m.-.m\001.+.!.c\011.x\011.-XX.a.t.v.s.m.v\001.-.t.v.m.v.c0.a\046.-.v.s@.w.t.c.c.Z.m\012.%.w.d.aY.o.d.A.m.+@.a`
- Content is empty.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jVj9V9pKE/69f8WSRrIxn4tBkRiVotfSq1St9aiAnpAEBUPgkqBo4P7rvbObIBD69rztKdl95pmPndnZbPocPv36/Lnk7drOjuO1C53CVsnd0be3naKrbxc7bbuju3rBKOrFIil@Cr0IKd7YHPft8BnpeqFgepPhYBSh0@pD5fTUqpo4eht66NGLnEHQyefZzBn0@3bgivua671owdj3UWE/T/L5VPm8cvXV4nic8pAynBtgIpGP6UMqz5KBMuPmbn/WazcPP66OrIKub83B8@8/ajentw/V75eXx9Uri5gNxPHxl8qPrw/Xx5c/at/rZeltxiELvaFWPs9WNUDDQdidJDPpS6Jy9z80vP7YtyMPhU@MPxhGMHwdjNxw6HejfN72u3aIlEck8DGROP6QmwmWQJ9CPl//eXpaPTuyyswHpv5cM3zqdiKTjRHlpYDnPA0Q/1mkngn1nANHhYHv7uch9S@2j7gc6th@6HHT6bKMmWbak2nouUgItYn2ppkh/LxrAjP4jlpUibGAM1d1sIgHUIRKgJSXaEym0Qgp1RA1G7qy20JCoxlstoTp48gbIjUxrt0b27wWlysm3zbrptYM2Pwc3N2rajPQNLNdMWfJtHFP7RBS4LWhZkbLYElfxwghvDbIgDu76xghoB1kiaV1jOhFXutmiVvr2C7wHrIYeHYy2PbOOkYIKIfZ9W2tY4RAiC9Z4vY6RnTIWCcbtr6OER0y5mVj3F3HCDF4bZR1XVjHCAHt1yxxZx0jBYhnkiWW1jFSgBjfssTddYwUIJ73bBH032AQjp1ddHEdIwRyG2U9G@sY0SGcfjbfO@sY0SEcN@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@2RZz@zCdStgjl/MBiiYBChvh05T93gkQOqMF@uhEWtjYnIYlPYRElnOTbTkwkPk3/mkw02oTRoRtaIQmcwSnMFEZmmGAvmR5cKM0EUf/1Vr5wdW4L6qquK2lWdpq4TVVLt9BmpL2pffbn4pr4nI9WBXwl@I@DTecKAcaqRozYIUSfsV7m5UW3GCSmbcZS5VdXRqSNjGyAgHKqvIHHg7x21RgrqxgZArmrfqgN4VKjnQ9UWPlW/16@O61eWIHzCw1E3iDpw2WAr4VMRN311kOKIcJ34FY4cS/hyfFKrx7B1pNDzXDEcwTUPs@GsMw6cqDsI0Dk@EuMfjWf5byy2rCMThi1JWsiPsRiPvGg8ClBOAs5C8m0hAXyfLCR/LyTU3EJwtSKgLhWyJL7Bl2J8aQGLhaEoZkq@XHDGuCrGbP2oukBP8KV892EbrrF@N/D29QNeLytLgX1NHPDEZNv3nvWGBLuY48QVCCXQuvuf1P04sJZ8V/DZPKKzKQdbDfJPr8rdCC25HsLSX5@6vodzkFJxsJxJmMQATqdjfAOyhSDANflaPpJ9kVaRKcbXFnBM3/K94DF6wteiSTd8De7btT3LN8UxxkcWrCWMRvharkmSTETxX46tizs4koxS2SiKs4WTLng/xycrjh/wmVyV7@RbMT6zOPWhjOrQtjZyPafbh/svLNZ79EbwHI4jzqxaoG7eQQw0FtpzEK6xs1fN56t7xZLIDgITsOq/3L3R2Cq2eDjD7izDUKqpcnJWAAWXEjViQEKqlrVVEOOEAp8mUTcYezOacUqt7hkl4OwXd0QKJc4XbhPL4q2Fb0VUVYySSatnnuO7zdultTrz7J/jq5UkhHPBzXKxXqAmPflajGuWzjz2LLaPIf09um3lnqK0rGtaKDqrtRgIdWixea@1lPrRwjVkFLP@FDfpHlhy@LpomvVoJvhCZr5y0I40wzmYXbAtcm1d7FFuqnu9UHr7o9L@75XeP8KgWiwMZSWUaL6YJ@hda0XUB9EzbBYEX27nmMqXhG1sQ0KTLf6N7vBzbB@AumTTTJRv0oyYixNj0yJKYRPbe7q4SWsGz6Wk/pO110s75iZdLO5t@iLsGHDDqRvw4lJhN3JldOeN4B7XfemGYIajG4UWxT7o7fsHvQ2/7G/0ymyssTHUaJacsBCZpbdgO8DHZuZs5qaOyAmL4DqQiRXWx9m9/vH3h28/K3lpJjcVuAjCS5R@gyuj4JlMnTGMXAEJSOkU5m9XuFid47xIP0KXwvHYZk7e2jFsXLahnyXJlKTeHqaHMN20kPIk/b10CgPR/P0y6HJdz/fgOx3qDK2QHk/QIJJU2wN1iSQtwd40NWZRItAnyaEvJfPWTDDpm4r@BwVc5RzE/hNjTDtk0Kef5ACO1sBFDl0DKXVjhTCd4mEI8gEadl3Zi7p9Tx46w7H8Er6brh154nINjD9/gKPI7vpwvTaWEkyv@HGJXrPYZU6Y2q/PYAvZllIgxo5R2to2SkiIbcni9dlx/Sh9a9hwKeE@/d/1T62m2aEPDgoAL3yOiQRehzsi/OFQmJQHcxsDTuZ1UZhO7NEj5KA2QWnlJp/QL2N3t7CztVvaIdv/AQ)

### Usage

A single line that matches `^[0-9]+$`, ending with EOF, is given from stdin. A single `Y` is output if and only if truthy.

### Algorithm

1. Let l1 be a list storing each digit in reverse order.
2. Let s be 0.
3. Let l2 be an empty list.
4. If l1 is empty, go to step 9.
5. Pop one value from l1 and let it be n. Push n*(s+1) onto l2.
6. If last value on l2 is more than 9, subtract 9 from it.
7. Let s be 1-s.
8. Go to step 4.
9. Calculate (sum of each item in l2)%10.
10. If step 9 resulted in 0, the program returns truthy; otherwise falsey.

### With comments

```
# getchar() unil EOF
# substract 48 for each character
.w0.-.i.c\001.+.aXX.z
# at this point stack is -1, [0-9], ..., [0-9], 48.
# add 1 to -1 so: 0, ..., 48.
# move 0 to bottom: [0-9], ..., 48, 0.
.a\001.+.t.v.m.vXX.z
# loop
# every time loop begins, bottom should be [01].
# also heap should be same as bottom.
.aQJ.zXX.z
  # to: [0-9], [01], ..., 48, ..., [01]... I think
  # WTF did I do here?
  .a.v.m.v.c.m.+.c.t.-.m.v.t.v.m.-.mXX.z
  # multiply [0-9] to ([01]+1)
  .a\001.+.!XX.z
  # subtract 9 if more than 9
  .a.c\011.x\011.-XX.aXX.z
  # move top to bottom, replacing it
  .a.t.v.s.m.vXX.z
  # alt for [01] xor 1; subtract from 1
  # then move to bottom
  .a\001.-.t.v.m.vXX.z
# break if top equals 48
.a.c0.aXX.z
# make 48 to 10, then remove botton [01]
# OBTW reversed, but whatever
.a\046.-.v.sXX.z
# loop
.a@.wXX.z
  # if size is 1; then
  .a.t.c.c.ZXX.z
    # modulo by 10
    .a.m\012.%XX.z
    # if it is 0; then print Y and exit; else exit; fi
    .a.w.d.aY.o.d.AXX.z
  # fi; push (pop+pop)
  .a.m.+
# end of loop
.a@.a
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), <s><sup>12</sup></s> 11 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @lyxal reminding me about multibyte lambdas.*

```
ṘÞTf‡d∑ẇ∑₀Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%98%C3%9ETf%E2%80%A1d%E2%88%91%E1%BA%87%E2%88%91%E2%82%80%E1%B8%8A&inputs=1234567812345678&header=&footer=)

Explanation:

```
             # Implicit input
Ṙ            # Reverse
 ÞT          # Transpose
   f         # Flatten list
    ‡  ẇ     # For every second element:
     d       #   Double
      ∑      #   Sum digits
        ∑    # Sum all elements
         ₀Ḋ  # x % 10 == 0?
             # Implicit output
```

Comment: [use a multi byte lambda for 11 bytes](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E1%B9%98%C3%9ETf%E2%80%A1d%E2%88%91%E1%BA%87%E2%88%91%E2%82%80%E1%B8%8A&inputs=1234567812345678&header=&footer=)

Comment: @lyxal Wow. I can't believe I forgot those existed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## [Julia 1.0](http://julialang.org/), <s>51</s> 50 bytes

```julia
~=digits;!n=(k=~n;k[2:2:end]*=2;sum(sum,.~k)%10<1)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDLasMwEAXQvb7CCSlIZSjWcyQ7/pLSRSEPFDuTkgd05V93ZELaoasupDkguHfQ4TbkT/09TWO3yft8vbQL6mTfjdT276YxzZY2H6@daS@3oywH3sZeveh6rdW0O50rqjJV0qVk0KaIGkEb63zA@JyAP481s2Y2zI7ZMwdmZOb5CSy64EtxSHP1A/MMyUWPIRXNsBHLbtE6iOBYhfizfA3iN92C@G98iA59uaFW4uuc6TqQXK6oqVZyQWqpRPnV6Q4)

Answer (score 1):

## GNU sed, 140 bytes

(including +1 for the `-r` flag)

```
s/^(..)*.$/0&/
s/(.)./\1x&/g
s/x[5-9]/1&/g
s/[0x]//g
s/[789]/&6/g
s/[456]/&3/g
s/[369]/&11/g
s/[258]/&1/g
s/.{10}//g
s/.+/false/
s/^$/true/
```

Sed is almost never the most natural language for arithmetic, but here we go:

```
#!/bin/sed -rf

# zero-pad to even length
s/^(..)*.$/0&/
# double every other digit
s/(.)./\1x&/g
# add carry (converts mod-9 to mod-10)
s/x[5-9]/1&/g
# convert sum to unary
s/[0x]//g
s/[789]/&6/g
s/[456]/&3/g
s/[369]/&11/g
s/[258]/&1/g
# remove whole tens
s/.{10}//g
# output 'true' or false
s/.+/false/
s/^$/true/
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP - 136 characters

```
function t($c){foreach($a=str_split(strrev($c)) as $k=>&$v){$v=array_sum(str_split(($k % 2)!==0?2*$v:$v));}return !(array_sum($a)% 10);}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>23</s> 20 bytes (non competing)

```
P!Utn:2X\!*t9>+s10\~
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/matl#@x@gGFqSZ2UUEaOoVWJpp11saBBT9/@/uomlpZG5saWFuaGZOgA)

Outputs 1 for a valid number, 0 otherwise.

Saved three bytes thanks to Luis Mendo's suggestions.

### Explanation

```
P       % flip the order of elements
!       % transpose into column vector
U       % convert char matrix to numeric
t       % duplicate the vector
n       % find the length
:       % create a new vector length n (1, 2, 3, ... n)
2       % number literal
X\      % take it mod 2, to make the new vector (1, 2, 1, ..., (n-1) mod 2 +1)
!       % transpose
*       % element-wise product
t       % duplicate
9       % push 9
>       % 1 if it is greater than 9
+       % add the vectors, this makes the last digit of each the same as the sum of the digits
s       % add them
10      % number literal
\       % mod 10
~       % logical 'not' (element-wise)
        % (implicit) convert to string and display
```

Answer (score 1):

## [K (oK)](https://github.com/JohnEarnest/ok), 28 bytes

**Solution:**

```
~10!+/48!,/$(1+2!!#x)*48!|x:
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y9bNz/7/v87QQFFb38RCUUdfRcNQ20hRUblCUwvIr6mwUjKxtDQyN7a0MDc0U/r/HwA)

**Examples:**

```
~10!+/48!,/$(1+2!!#x)*48!|x:"1234567812345670"
1
~10!+/48!,/$(1+2!!#x)*48!|x:"1234567812345678"
0
```

**Explanation:**

```
~10!+/48!,/$(1+2!!#x)*48!|x: / the solution
                          x: / save input as variable x
                         |   / reverse it
                      48!    / mod with 48 (converts ascii -> int)
            (       )*       / multiply with stuff in brackets
                  #x         / length of x
                 !           / til, the range 0..x-1
               2!            / mod with 2 (0 1 2 3 -> 0 1 0 1)
             1+              / add 1 (0 1 0 1 -> 1 2 1 2)
           $                 / convert to string
         ,/                  / flatten string
      48!                    / convert this into integers
    +/                       / sum over the list
 10!                         / modulo 10
~                            / negate (so 1 for truthy, 0 for falsy)
```

**Extra:**

A couple of 30-byte solutions in **K4**, not quite as short...

```
~.*|$+/,/10\:'((#x)#1 2)*.:'x:
~.*|$+/.:'',/$((#x)#1 2)*.:'x:
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 20 [bytes](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt/wiki/Codepage)

```
ĐḶ⌊⁺⇹ą↔⇹ř⁻2%⁺*ŚƩ1ᴇ%¬
```

Explanation:

```
                        Implicit input
Đ                       Duplicate input
 Ḷ⌊⁺                    Get length of integer in base-10 (floor(log_10(input))+1)
    ⇹                   Swap top two on stack
     ą↔                 Convert input to an array of digits, and reverse
       ⇹                Swap top two on stack
        ř⁻              Push [0,1,2,...,floor(log_10(input))]
          2%            Take previous array element-wise mod 2
            ⁺           Increment each element of the array
             *          Elementwise multiplication of the arrays
              Ś         Elementwise sum of digits
               Ʃ        Sum up array
                1ᴇ%     Mod 10
                   ¬    Negate (this returns false if not 0, and true otherwise)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f//yISHO7Y96ul61LjrUfvOI62P2qYA6aMzHzXuNlIFCmodnXVspeHDLe2qh9b8/29uaWlkbmxpYW5oDAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 77 bytes

```kotlin
mapIndexed{i,c->(""+(2-(length%2 xor i%2))*(c-'0')).sumBy{it-'0'}}.sum()%10<1
```

### Beautified

```kotlin
mapIndexed { i, c ->
    ("" + (2 - (length % 2 xor i % 2)) * (c - '0')).sumBy { it - '0' }
}.sum() % 10 < 1
```

### Test

```kotlin
data class Test(val input: String, val output: Boolean)

val tests = listOf(
        Test("49927398716", true),
        Test("49927398717", false),
        Test("1234567812345670", true),
        Test("1234567812345678", false),
        Test("79927398710", false),
        Test("79927398711", false),
        Test("79927398712", false),
        Test("79927398713", true),
        Test("79927398714", false),
        Test("79927398715", false),
        Test("79927398716", false),
        Test("79927398717", false),
        Test("79927398718", false),
        Test("79927398719", false),
        Test("374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368", true),
        Test("374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834", false),
        Test("8", false),
        Test("0", true)
)

fun String.f() =
mapIndexed{i,c->(""+(2-(length%2 xor i%2))*(c-'0')).sumBy{it-'0'}}.sum()%10<1
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    for ((input, expectedOut) in tests) {
        val actualOut = input.f()
        if (actualOut != expectedOut) {
            System.err.println("$input $expectedOut $actualOut")
        }
    }
}
```

### TIO

[TryItOnline](https://tio.run/##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)

Answer (score 1):

## [Dart](https://www.dartlang.org/), 120 bytes

```
f(s,{i=0})=>s.split('').reversed.map(int.parse).map((n)=>i++%2>0?n*2:n).map((n)=>n>9?n-10+1:n).fold(0,(p,e)=>p+e)%10==0;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZLPToQwEMbv@xS9bFoESUtL/0hgTz6F8UAEIslubQruZcOz44C6K8Ye7GHmm@/XmcNkmtqP89yRIbn0JZ2ishrSwR37kWAcpb49t35om/RUO9LbMXU1lNFaEguf@zjeZxU92Lvswf7wbWUO9p7RmC1293ZsCE2IS1pgLm6jPaNlSYv5VPeWRJcdQufaoxGV6Ak0QlgYkylutGISo/Ulv4HaApZxkUulvzLFKFn8P6HG313qOo5ux90AC4EsBHgIiBDIQ0CGgAoBHQJmC7gSMod1SLMs5FMsWRqhcyUNqEVwqYXKIeL/NmoFq9ZcXBtvIyiG/FzsII5wHf6xfnkl5H09BISch1MjHdRRAcYEcZo/AA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 37 bytes

```perl6
(*.flip.comb >>*>>[1,2]).comb.sum%%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDNboMwDADg8/IUVtVOUCYgJLETTXDcC2y3dYduA6kStBWsh2paX52Fhg005bAcYuuT82Mfy7bGvjnDbQV5H6zjqt4d47dD8wpFsS6KZ36XvYRXiLtTs1rxtL9n1aGFoN7tyy6ET3bTbc9QBVGTbN6jJLwsNh@Q57C4WHiMlgn76qUxGQmjiSNc11N7Ktmk5PRhW3cl45mQCkmPMXXFf1SPxfR7Rzq/Y2Lu58zPYva9SaW/WPkZ/Ux@1n42cxYkUdm@0Qydu2SIaKRWhMZmQyJQS1J2d///7ylNdqBayPGxn8m6uX8D)

A Whatever lambda that takes a number and returns a boolean.

#### Explanation:

```perl6
 *.flip                  # Reverse the number
       .comb             # Split to list of digits
             >>*>>       # Multiply each element by:
                  [1,2]  # The list 1,2,1,2,1,2...
(                      ).comb           # Split the list to a list of digits
                             .sum       # Get the digit sum
                                 %%10   # Return if it is divisible by 10
```

Answer (score 1):

**[Julia](https://julia-lang.org), 67 bytes**

```
x=digits(n)
sum(x[1:2:end])+sum(reduce(vcat,digits.(x[2:2:end]*2)))
```

Answer (score 1):

## [MathGolf](https://github.com/maxbergmark/mathgolf), 11 bytes

```
▒xôï¥)*Σ+♂÷
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc8tDkIxDABg35sAZlu7/hwHAwgIBoHmCAgSNEFjSPDMc4h3kbEFAg0K035p2rRdTTeL@Xo5q3U47LflWi7382j8OE2G467caiWzJGgqkeFrgZiQMou@c/gtKMinOzhH5@SMzuScndlZnP0uAxTi3I5g62e80DMbaRa2pg5kJckt/j2g0h5TJFAITw)

At least I tied with Jelly, I can't really see a way to remove a byte from this.

### Explanation

```
▒             split to list of chars/digits
 x            reverse int/array/string
  ô           start block of length 6 (for-each)
   ï          index of current loop
    ¥         modulo 2
     )        increment
      *       pop a, b : push(a*b)
       Σ      digit sum
        +     add to the counter (implicitly calculates 0+x when stack only has one element)
              Block ends here
         ♂    push 10
          ÷   is divisible
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 73 bytes

```hs
i#0=0
i#n|m<-mod n 10=i*(m+sum[-9|m>4])+m+(1-i)#div n 10
f n=mod(0#n)10<1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jY/LCoMwEEX3fsWAXWhVSMxjEqj9keJCsNJQE6WvVf/dxraUSKF0k7mHuXAmh@Z83Pf9NJmYVCQysbvbTWGHFhxQUpl1YrPz1e4KfbdbXqeZzRJamDRuze1ZiTpwle8nJHYpJRs62cY4qKAdIhhPxl1gBbYZoYMd17pEphVSmQMtGRcS1XuSHPCzZjkw5FL4ldRz6RXmKTVXAqX2aQ5MKo7CvzmQ@ocQv4QqFC7sNIQyBB6CCEGGgCEsPPr/jyn0VyrmlaqeHg)

Answer (score 1):

## APL(NARS), 37 chars, 74 bytes

```
{0=10∣+/{+/10 10⊤⍵}¨v+v×0=2∣⍳≢v←⌽⍎¨⍵}
```

test:

```
  f←{0=10∣+/{+/10 10⊤⍵}¨v+v×0=2∣⍳≢v←⌽⍎¨⍵}
  f '1234567812345670'
1
  f '49927398717'
0
  f '1234567812345678'
0
  f '79927398710'
0
  f '79927398719'
0
  f '374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368'
1
  f '374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834'
0
  f ,'8'
0
  f ,'0'
1
```

comment:

```
{0=10∣+/{+/10 10⊤⍵}¨v+v×0=2∣⍳≢v←⌽⍎¨⍵}
                                ⍎¨⍵ for each element of ⍵ (that would be char digits) convert in int
                             v←⌽    reverse the array result of above, and assign it to variable v
                           ⍳≢        produce all index of above v that are 1..≢v
                        0=2∣         produce one array of boolean where 0 means even index, 1 odd
                    v+v×            multipy that array for v itself (means get only odd ones the other 0)
                                    and sum it to v (so we have v with elements index odd duplicate)
       {+/10 10⊤⍵}¨                convert each element of the array of 2 digits base 10 than sum
   10∣+/                            sum all element mod 10
 0=                                if result is 0 return 1 (true), else return 0 (false)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <del>83</del> 82 bytes

```php
foreach(str_split(strrev($argn))as$x=>$d)$m+=$d+($d%10+$d/5|0)*$x&=1;echo!($m%10);
```

As standalone program, call with `php -F`.  Input is `STDIN`, output is to `STDOUT` as bool (1 or empty).

```php
$ echo 49927398716|php -F luhn.php
1

$ echo 49927398717|php -F luhn.php

$ echo 1234567812345670|php -F luhn.php
1
```

[Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##jZJdT8IwFIav7a84LlU2IXFjW7syB/FCogmJXHgnZqlsMBOQZS2GRP3t2A6EDNPEm/XNefqer7Usyu3NoCxKhLDMhRSQwDM6awWMdanPIuqRFiR9eKrWeacRp3V8yBeiBl7XD0JCo/3pHl0Af3HUNNNDVtcEPBPomoDfaPwYD0yG0ASICVATMM7HmsCnAQnVSgjTS9kJfRIWRCElTCktfBIFNFTfxkj/NUdUrTzyT@Y@afH4w9BLjNBsVeV8WtiwfxVcAObV/F1fwlUuwIFPBICX6r24sVL5tFjtrnTA6k2kpYOr11RIXknbibe/GYWsUlEu3qRWVf5h1ybH4QJvkj7OHLxsJzhr2zi78Nw2zq7DL9e5wpvLxIt1lXMbLxVRKfdVVZV5LtPZYi0K24Ek2XU4AGsix1wIC3paDm8fRtah1fH9OL17HMXoe/sD)

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt) v2.0a0, 14 bytes

```
¬ÔxÈ*ÒYu)ìxÃvA
```

The first byte can be removed if I took input as array of chars.

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=2.0a0&code=rNR4yCrSWXUp7HjDdkE=&input=IjEyMzQ1Njc4MTIzNDU2Nzgi)

```
¬                   //Split (implicit) input into list of chars
 Ô                  //Reverse
  xÈ                //Get the sum of every char after passing through the following function
    *               //  Multiply the element
     ÒYu)           //  By the index modulus 2 plus 1 (Odd -> 2, Even -> 2)
         ìx         //  And take the sum of the digits
  Ã                 //Close function
vA                  //And check if result is divisible by 10
```

Comment: Oh, didn't see you'd posted this before I fixed mine. Don't forget, you only have 'til Tuesday to post 3 more solutions and qualify for the additional 300 rep bounty.

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 46 bytes

```r
function(x,y=rev(x)*1:2)!sum(y%%10+y%/%10)%%10
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHdasMwDIXv8xYLhMpbWOP4R/Ygz1JCcGkgSUPsjObpM4uVdh67mS50zicQHFvLPqyXqdnP69SF/jrBrdyaxX3Cjb3yj5q9@HWErSh49bYVxyiM/B6cD6eu9c43HWS5tLZGYQ1ynZc/EQl5LaTSaO5a/TEzNMPHWpUiT7FOUaQoU1Qp6hQxxV8xLKFAqVVMqS3l/Dak2kqjUNvoyAhtJKrY/7NjMD7eCJmzzLfzPGzw/NjycZLA6EbQ@vdpHd3Sd@AG8GHx89AHCOXhwKiy/Qs)

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>15</s> 13 bytes

*Edit: -2 bytes thanks to Razetime*

```
¬→dṁΣzod*¢ḣ2↔
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CaR22TUh7ubDy3uCo/RevQooc7Fhs9apvy////aBMdSyA00jHXMQbSFkDaUMcsFgA)

```
¬                   # logical NOT of
 →d                 # last decimal digit of
   ṁΣ               # sum of sums of results of
     z              # zipping two lists together
         ¢ḣ2        # list 1: [1,2] repeated
            ↔       # list 2: input, reversed
      o             # using these two functions:
       d*           # decimal digits of product
```

Comment: [13 bytes using `cycle`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CaR22TUh7ubDy3uCo/RevQooc7Fhs9apvy////aBMdSyA00jHXMQbSFkDaUMcsFgA "Husk – Try It Online")

Comment: Nice!  Thanks!  Another new function used for the first time...

Answer (score 1):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), 52 bytes

```zsh
for j (${(Oas::)1})((s+=++i%2?j:j*2.2%10))
<<<$s[-1]
```

[Try it Online..](https://tio.run/##jZJNa8MwDIbv/RWipGAvdET@kp1l7LbrLrttg5aRkYWwQr1cVvrbM6cpa5aAqQ7WC49f2ZL946uuaRk/dB@7PdTAkgN72vo853jkjPn0Pk0/V@KhzusbcStWmHG@KIoi8S9rfOuOi6atvoIdyvdqB@sSlgnC6zdsmhYS3CzvYNgCyjlB0llCA6d43rflFNGAHreNPzMUUmlD9pyzkW2C7NhGfyWzWckLwwgTESanHVyQith0hJkIowizEeZmTJIyOozLuH5gg@izccpqMi6oXkhjFemwjlq81mopPIaVanzs/JLZ7A/g/zih7hc)

Parse input into array and reverse it: `${(Oas::)1}`. Then iterate over the array elements. 
`0` is `truthy`, non-zero is `falsy`.

<sub>From my work, the Visa test number (`4111 1111 1111 1111`) is embedded in my brain.</sub>

<sub>Previous efforts: <s>[55 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZG9CsIwFIV3nyJDC4kFaX5vUituri5uIihSqaVYaOii@Ow1NeLQSsA73HM4HyfDzd2Wfd1h8ugvTYsqhKMH3p5slhH6JBjbZIWT5Epitq6yas4WLKYpIbM8z6O9df7QP2d1V97cC6g4lw2KKDrWnZPjEnmEhDEMuNFA1TgAH1DGhVSgP5r@TLVP4VtO0Xs2p9oWY0YDjAUY92zXdhMkAjUZYCrAIMB0gJkJ4yCUdIdSZjiVN4MqI7QEZZwbDFdagHT7v5YG9wOai/4F)</s> <s>[61 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZG9CsIwFIX3PkWGFhI72PzepFbcXF3cRFCk0paiYOhi6bPX1IiDSsA73HM4HyfDzd1WY9th0o/1kkbn6w01CMc93hxtnhM6EIxtusR1mpKErZq8mTE2p1lCM0KioijinXV@Pw5R21UX9w4qT9UVxRQd2s7JYYE8QsIYBtxooOozAB9QxoVUoF@a/Uy1T@FdztBz1sfWlp@MBhgLMO7Z9tZ9IRGoyQBTAQYBpgPMfDEOQkl3KGWmU3kzqTJCS1DGuclwpQVIt/9raXA/oLkYHw)</s> <s>[72 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZG9asMwFIV3P4WgNkgpJNbvlVybblmzdAuBmOBgg2lAwkuNn92Rq5DBKYJquOdwPs4drn5cO/cDJmPSVbOtcDriQ@2KgtCJJNebRR3CI91u0zc7EYzde9Vl7NMeu1OxjA1jO5pnNCckKcsyPTrvT/OU9EP77bei5tLeUErRuR@8nD9QQEgYw4AbDVStAwgBZVxIBfqh@Z@pDik8yzn6ffu6d82a0QhjEcYD@7LDCxKRmowwFWEQYTrCzAvjIJT0h1JmOVUwiyojtARlvFsMV1qA9PN/LQ3@BzQX8x0)</s> <s>[77 bytes](https://tio.run/##lZG9asMwFIV3P4WgCkgtpPq/kmu3W9cu3UwgoaTYYBKQ8BLjZ3elqnRIiqAa7jmcj3OHq0vo13EidK6GdvUtwTN5O4S6pnyh1efZowGRmW@3@M4vNLQ4POBu2Ihn9uK7YVeTNO@FeOSMbjjbVU3T4C4kuy7VOPWnuBodP/ozwhztxynK/gllhJRzAqSzwM11ADngQiptwP4o@zO1OYXfMkPf7/UwhuM14wUmCkxm9u6nG6QKNV1gpsCgwGyBuRsmQRkdD2VcOlU2SY1TVoNx0SUjjVWg4/xfy0L8ASvV@gU)</s></sub>

Answer (score 1):

## [dc](https://www.gnu.org/software/bc/manual/dc-1.05/html_mono/dc.html), 61 bytes

```
[A~rdZ1<S]dsSxz2%1=0[2*SaSaz1<LLaLalSx]dsLx[+z1<L]dsLxA%0=0zp
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2JpaWRubGlhbmj2P9qxriglytAmODalOLiiykjV0NYg2kgrODE4scrQxscn0ScxJ7gCKOlTEa0NEgEzHVUNbA2qCv7/BwA)

```
[A~rdZ1<S]dsSx # split: take quotient and remainder by 10, rotate quotient to top
z2%1=0 # if odd length, prepend 0 (I think. I poked it until it worked)
[2*SaSaz1<LLaLalSx]dsLx # double every other number, split them all
[+z1<L]dsLx # sum everything
A%0=0zp # if n%10 == 0, print 1; else, print 0
```

The last line works because:

1. Each register holds 0 by default
2. Comparisons attempt to execute whatever's in the specified register (`0` here)
3. Executing a number simply returns the number

So if we execute the contents of register `0`, then we have one item on the stack: 0. Otherwise, the stack is empty. Use `z` to convert this to a 0 or 1.

Answer (score 1):

### C (gcc), <s>126</s> 110 bytes

*-16 bytes thanks to ceilingcat*

```
#define e s[1][i]
c,b;main(i,s)char**s;{for(i=strlen(s[1]);i--;b+=e-=e/10?9:0)e-=48,e*=c++%2+1;return!(b%10);}
```

Input is taken through an argument and output uses exit codes, 0 for false and 1 for true

Explanation:

```
#define e s[1][i]
c,b;
main(i,s) // i, c, and b are ints for program use
char**s; // argv, used for input
{
    for(i=strlen(s[1]); i--; b+=e-=e/10?9:0) // iterate backwards through string, and add to the total (b) while also doing the digit add
        e-=48, // subtract '0'
        e*=c++%2+1; // double each odd index
    return!(b%10); // check if b ends in 0 and return that
}
```

Comment: Suggest `e<<=c++%2` instead of `e*=c++%2+1`

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal), 16 bytes

```
₀τƛ¥₂ßd&›₀τ∑;∑₀Ḋ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%E2%82%80%CF%84%C6%9B%C2%A5%E2%82%82%C3%9Fd%26%E2%80%BA%E2%82%80%CF%84%E2%88%91%3B%E2%88%91%E2%82%80%E1%B8%8A&inputs=49927398716&header=&footer=)

```
₀τ               # Digits...
  ƛ         ;    # Map
   ¥₂            # If register is even
     ßd          # Double
       &›        # Increment register
         ₀τ      # Digits...
           ∑     # Sum
             ∑   # Sum of all...
              ₀Ḋ # is divisible by 10?
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Fig](https://github.com/Seggan/Fig), \$10\log_{256}(96)\approx\$ 8.231 bytes

```
]SeSn2@h$f
```

[Try it online!](https://fig.fly.dev/#WyJdU2VTbjJAaCRmIiwiNDk5MjczOTg3MTYiXQ==)

Outputs using inverted logic: positive integer for falsey, 0 for truthy

```
]SeSn2@h$f
         f # Digits of number
        $  # Reverse
    n2@    # For every other item in the list
       h   # Unhalve (double)
  eS       # Digit sum of each
 S         # Sum
]          # Take the last digit (equivalent to mod 10)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 8 bytes

```
fṘ⁽dẇṠ∑t
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/#WyIiLCIiLCJm4bmY4oG9ZOG6h+G5oOKIkXQiLCIiLCI0OTkyNzM5ODcxNiJd)

Outputs 0 for truthy, any positive integer for falsey.

### Explained

```
fṘ⁽dẇṠ∑t
fṘ       # reverse the list of digits of the input
  ⁽dẇ    # double each odd-indexed digit
     Ṡ∑t # sum each number, and take the tail of the sum
```

Answer (score 1):

## [><>](https://esolangs.org/wiki/Fish), <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
00@:}2%1+$c%*:a%$9)++{1+$1l3=.
n;a%0=
```

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##S8sszvj/38DAwarWSNVQWyVZVcsqUVXFUlNbuxrINcwxttXjyrNOVDWw/f//v26xiaWlkbmxpYW5oRkA)

**Explanation**

```
00                                 # init sum and counter to 0
  @:}2%1+                          # set counter to 1 if even and 2 if odd
         $c%*                      # mod current number by 12 and multiply by counter
               :a%$9)++            # sum digits and add to total sum
                       {1+$        # increment counter
                           1l3=.   # jump to next row if done, else skip init on 1st row
n;a%0=                             # print sum mod 10 == 0
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `t!`, 8 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
drŻɗ⁺×ʂS
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faFm0UomiUuyCpaUlaboW61KKju4-Of1R467D0081BS8pTkouhkot2GBoZGxiamZuAaUNIOIA)

##### Or 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md) flagless:

```
drŻɗ⁺×ʂSt~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWG1KKju4-Of1R467D0081BZfULSlOSi6GSi7YYGhkbGJqZm4BpQ0g4gA)

##### Explanation

```python
drŻɗ⁺×ʂSt~  # Implicit input
dr          # Cast to digits; reverse the list
  Ż         # Without popping, push [0..length)
   ɗ⁺       # Mod 2 of each; increment each
     ×      # Multiply elementwise
      ʂ     # Sum the digits of each number
       S    # Sum the resulting list
        t   # Pop and push the last digit
         ~  # And check if this equals 0
            # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Pyth, 19 bytes (non-competing)

Non-competing since Pyth is newer than this challenge.

```
!%s.esj*b@S2kT_jQTT
```

A program that takes input of a string on STDIN and prints `True` or `False` as appropriate.

[Try it online](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=%21%25s.esj%2ab%40S2kT_jQTT&debug=0) or [verify all test cases](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=Q%21%25s.esj%2ab%40S2kT_jQTT&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=49927398716%0A49927398717%0A1234567812345670%0A1234567812345678%0A79927398710%0A79927398711%0A79927398712%0A79927398713%0A79927398714%0A79927398715%0A79927398716%0A79927398717%0A79927398718%0A79927398719%0A374652346956782346957823694857692364857368475368%0A374652346956782346957823694857692364857387456834%0A8%0A0&debug=0)

**How it works**

```
!%s.esj*b@S2kT_jQTT  Program. Input: Q
               jQT   Yield the base-10 representation of Q as a list, giving the digits
              _      Reverse
   .e                Enumerated map, with elements as b and indices as k:
          S2           Yield [1, 2]
         @  k          Modular indexing with k, yielding 1 for even indices and 2 for odd
                       indices
       *b              Multiply by b
      j      T         Yield the digits
     s                 Sum
  s                  Sum the resulting list
 %                T  Modulo 10
!                    Logical not, yielding True for 0 and False otherwise
                     Implicitly print
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 85 bytes

```
proc L n {expr ([regsub -all . [string rev $n] {+([incr i]%2?&:&*2%10+(&>4))}])%10<1}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDNisIwEADge55iDlpaxaX5nUSW9QVkX6D0oKVIodaSVhFKn72boCzDnjaHzJeByUwyVu0y1CN8g3JOoHQWuVl6f6vgCB1M9bP3kBa@vgz3M@xObQsfUAyjb7oL@PoBq66EaZsWTVd5aMq1OCT7ZCPWPN@myZfKsrnMwuGTz0t7PfXxTkZaQVwkga8EF1Jpg/Yd878Jy/C3JCfmxIJYEitiTWyIkZj2ckyiMjoMYVwc44UYjVNWo3FBEdJYhTrs/y6wGB5mpWKW5WyGqb@PAxTH@MHz8gM)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 86 bytes

```
proc L n {expr !(([regsub -all . [string rev $n] {+([incr i]%2?&:&*2%10+(&>4))}])%10)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jdDNioMwEADge55iFlrRLS2av0l66L6A7AuIh65IEawr0ZaC@OxugmUZemoOmS8Dk5lkrNplqEf4BmktR2ENZnrp3W8FOXQw1Y/ewUccF66@DLcf2J/bFg5QDKNrugu4@g6broRpFxdNVzloyi3/io7RJ99m6S6OTjJJ5jLxh2Re2uu5D5cy0gvCIglcExkXUmk0z5i@JgzD/5KUOCPmxIJYEitiTYzEtJdlAqVWfghtwxgrQtRWGoXaegUIbSQqv79dYNA/zAjJDEvZDFN/Gwco8vC/8/IH)

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 119 bytes

```
proc L n {expr !(([join [lmap a [lreverse [split $n ""]] {expr [incr i]%2?$a:[join [split [expr 2*$a] ""] +]}] +])%10)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jZBNasMwEIX3OsU0OJC0G1t/I3XTC4ReQGhhjBYujiNktxSCz@5KsSlDV9Vi3sfwnmakuRvWKczwDtJajsIabPQa062DC4xwD98xwdPp5D5u/QhuuLYR2qwpfIU0BXBTHPoZqhEOB@93v@vHLkHvj/ytal/36GZ0DwN/rlpfEvDil1LOx6Y@L@vj@jyVkWWgHNLArdFwIZVGs2v9t2EY/kZqwg1hTlgQloQVYU0YCdNZlgmUWuUltC1rbFBUW2kUapupgNBGosr13wGD@WFGSGZYzRa4x895AnfJn@@X9Qc)

Answer (score 0):

## [bash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bash_(Unix_shell)), <s>109</s> <s>106</s> <s>90</s> 71 bytes

Output of `0` means `True`. Anything else means `False`.

```bash
for x in `rev<<<$1|fold -1`;{((s+=++i%2?x:(x*22/10)%10));}
echo $[s%10]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##lZHNaoQwFIX3PsVdzIBWhjG/NxmV7voE3ZWC046DQlBQLIL12W1sShdaAg0k5@R8nCxu3q59tZghjKagzpd728EIdQNFV35kWXYgn/fW3OBEinQKwz7O47g@0sfxEo4PlJ5JEh3tjtI5KN@rFg4vvb2/LnNghqqxj4KLCRRmsFKk4BBwrSkyrZDIbYAuIJRxIVH9aPJnqlyKv@UEvtfT1fTllhEPox7GHHvuhh3inprwMOlh6GHKw/SOMeRS2EFJvY7KmVWl5kqg1NathknFUdjzfy2F9gcU48sX)
 <s><sub>[90bytes](https://tio.run/##lZHLasMwFET3/gpBFbBrSvW@kh/prl/QXSg4KQ42mAQkXAzG3@7KVekiKYJqoRnNYbhwdTq6bh3GNJuTvl5t3dj2s6oqTJvkfLVpWuL5wS77Ps/LLJvRVOPZFv0TLeiCXI0P/Y7tyYvLp8Ll6fTI2DMl2Y6S93JJ2o/uivDBbc91SYaxu/g5KMQUNcPopSlRQEgYw4AbDVTdBhACyriQCvSPkj9THVL4LRP0fV6Pg2tvGY0wFmE8sDc73iERqckIUxEGEaYjzNwxDkJJvyhltlUFs6kyQktQxrvNcKUFSH//r6XB/4DmYv0C)</sub></s>
 <s><sub>[Alt-90bytes-backwards](https://tio.run/##lZHNasMwEITvfgpBHZAaTLX6l43SW5@gt1BIWqdYYBKIMBiMn92Vq9JDUgTVQTOaj2Fh9X4M3dIPmEzF2ZWwtK6cHmAuPi9XjL1rK2j8ztHGVxUhExojhtrXMKPgyj1uK082bEefw3aswxaPj4w9ASUboG/NXJw@ugsq92F9LnPRD905TkIpBnTohyiHBiWEhLVMc2s0qNtApwAYF1Jp86P0z9SkVP@WKfo@L8c@nG4ZZBjLMJ7Y63W4QyJTkxmmMkxnmMkwe8e4FkrGRSm7riqZVZUVRmplo1sNV0ZoGe//tYyOP2C4WL4A)</sub></s>

Answer (score 0):

## [Burlesque](https://github.com/FMNSSun/Burlesque), 33 bytes

```
riXX<-J2ENj2en2?***{XX++}ms10.%z?
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyotykktLixN/f@/KDMiwkbXy8jVL8soNc/IXktLqzoiQlu7NrfY0EBPtcr@/38TS0sjc2NLC3NDMwA)

```
ri         # Read input as int
XX         # Explode into digits
<-         # Reverse
J2EN       # Duplicate and take every 2nd starting from 1
j2en       # Take the other half
2?*        # Multiply each digit by 2
**         # Remerge arrays
{XX++}ms   # Sum the digits of multidigit and then sum result
10.%z?     # If result `mod` 10 is 0
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

-1 byte thanks to [south](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/110888/south)

```ruby
->n{n.digits.each_slice(2).map{_1+(2.*_2||0).digits.sum}.sum%10<1}
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72kqDSpcsEiN9ulpSVpuhY3nXTt8qrz9FIy0zNLivVSE5Mz4otzMpNTNYw09XITC6rjDbU1jPS04o1qagw0YcqKS3NrQYSqoYGNYS3UJN8CBbdoE0tLI3NjSwtzQ7NYLpCAoZGxiamZuQWUNoCIIpSZY1VmEQsxdMECCA0A)

Comment: `(2.*_2||0)` saves a byte

Comment: @south Nice. Thanks!