# 196 algorithm code golf

Tags: code-golf, palindrome

Write a short program for [196-algorithm](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/196-Algorithm.html).
The algorithm starts from an integer, then adds its reverse to it until a palindrome is reached.

e.g.

```
input = 5280
5280 + 0825 = 6105
6105 + 5016 = 11121
11121 + 12111 = 23232
output = 23232
```

**Input**

an integer, which is not a [lyrchrel number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lychrel_number) (that is, it does eventually yield a palindrome under this algorithm, rather than continuing infinitely)

**Output**

the palindrome reached.

Comment: @Nakilon please give a reason for your edit.

Comment: Because your question is probably the only one involving the 196 algorithm. Making single-use tags is not useful.

Comment: @Chris: It's a private beta with 34 questions so far; single-use tags is a normal thing at this point. Anyway, let's leave it as it is for now, retagging later is always an option :)

Comment: What I meant was, your question is likely to be the only one _ever_ to involve this topic, even in 2 years' time. :-)

Comment: @Chris: Well, 196-algorithm is a pretty popular one, going by many different names. Just to be sure, though, I'll post another question about it before the 2-year-time lapses ;)

Comment: I'm assuming you expect it to work for all positive integers not in [A023108](http://oeis.org/A023108)?

Comment: @GigaWatt It should *at least* work for all positive integers that fit in the <integer> type of the language that you use.

Comment: @Eelvex - So... when the input is `196`, what's the expected output?  It fits in the integer data type quite comfortably.

Comment: @GigaWatt the expected output in this case is the palindrome reached with input `196`, but since we wouldn't want to wait forever, I won't ask you to try it.

Comment: @GigaWatt also, I had missread your fist question :) Just don't bother with A023108s' case.

Comment: @Eelvex: How will Lychrel numbers be handled?

Comment: @Joel, as with A023108, just ignore them (act like you don't know about them); we don't know if any exists anyway.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### APL (22 characters)

```
{a≡⌽a←⍕(⍎⍵)+⍎⌽⍵:a⋄∇a}⍞
```

This works in Dyalog APL. Here's an explanation, from right to left:

- `{ ... }⍞`: Get input from the user as characters (`⍞`) and feed it to our function (`{ ... }`).
- Within the direct function (`⋄` separates statements, so we look at them from left to right):

  - `a≡⌽a←⍕(⍎⍵)+⍎⌽⍵ : a`: Evaluate (`⍎`) the right argument's (`⍵`) reverse (`⌽`), and add that to the evaluated version of the right argument itself. Then, format the result (`⍕`; i.e., give its character representation), assign (`←`) that to the variable `a`, and finally test if `a`'s reverse is equivalent to `a` (i.e., is `a` a palindrome?). If true, return `a`; otherwise...
  - `∇a`: Feed `a` back into our function (`∇` is implicit self-reference).

Example:

```
      {a≡⌽a←⍕(⍎⍵)+⍎⌽⍵:a⋄∇a}⍞
412371
585585
```

Comment: It saves a few characters to use numeric input. `{⍵=A←⍎⌽⍕⍵:⍵⋄∇A+⍵}⎕`. You save the braces, a reverse and an eval.

Answer (score 10):

## Python 2, 55 bytes

Following JPvdMerwe suggestion:

```python
n=input()
while`n`!=`n`[::-1]:n+=int(`n`[::-1])
print n
```

**Python 2, 62:**

```python
n=raw_input()
while n!=n[::-1]:n=`int(n)+int(n[::-1])`
print n
```

Comment: Hehe ..))))))))

Comment: By looking at `n` as an int you can shorten by 6 characters, check for the code: http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/75/62

Comment: Seems I accidentally included the new line vim sneakily added to the end of my file to my count. The real count is 55.

Answer (score 10):

### GolfScript, 29 chars

```
~]{{.`.-1%.@={;0}{~+1}if}do}%
```

---

**Selected commentary**

The meat of the program is the `do` loop, of course. So I'll just cover that.

1. `` .` `` copies the number and stringifies it.
2. `.-1%` copies that string version and reverses it.
3. `.@` copies the reversed version, and brings the original non-reversed version to the front.

So, say, the number is 5280. At this stage, the stack is: `5280 "0825" "0825" "5280"`. The stage is set for the comparison. (After the comparison, the stack will be left at `5280 "0825"` no matter what---the items to compare have been popped off.)

1. If the string and the reverse are the same, we don't care about the reversed string, so just pop it off (`;`) and return 0 (to end the `do` loop).
2. If they don't match, then evaluate (`~`) the reversed string (to make it a number), add (`+`) that to the original number, and return 1 (to continue the `do` loop).

Comment: Are you sure you didn't press random keys on your keyboard? It looks like that...

Comment: @M28: GolfScript looks even more like line noise than Perl, doesn't it? ;-)

Comment: I feel sorry for you, it must be painful to code that

Comment: @M28: That wasn't nearly as painful as the solution I wrote for [Luhn algorithm](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/172). Just think about that. :-P

Comment: Your family is worried about you

Comment: @M28 look at my answer, that's what I call random keys on keyboard!

Answer (score 7):

**Ruby — 56 chars**

```
x,r=gets
x="#{x.to_i+r.to_i}"until x==r=x.reverse
puts x
```

Answer (score 7):

Just exercising my Pyth skills, not a serious contender.

## Pyth, 16 bytes

```
L?bqb_by`+vbi_bTyz
```

Equivalent to Python 3:

```
y=lambda b:b if b==b[::-1] else y(str(eval(b)+int(b[::-1],10)))
print y(input())
```

Comment: Just trying some old challenges, already answered, so not serious contender.

Comment: Some challenge authors will update the accepted answer if a shorter solutions comes in, so I think it's fair to inform the OP, that this is not technically a valid submission. (Don't get me wrong, I like to answer old challenges with CJam for fun, too - and I just did a few minutes ago. I'm just saying, if you do, leave a note, that the language is newer than the challenge.)

Comment: Actually being "not a serious contender" makes an answer subject to deletion -- but I don't see any reason this shouldn't be considered a serious contender.

Answer (score 6):

## J 25 <sup><strike>27</strike> <strike>31</strike></sup>

```
f=:(+g)^:(~:g=.|.&.":)^:_
e.g.
f 5280
23232
```

Answer (score 6):

## CJam, <s>22</s> 21 bytes

CJam was created after this question was asked, so technically its an invalid submission. But I found the question interesting, so here goes:

```
r{__W%:X=0{~X~+s1}?}g
```

Explanation:

```
r{                 }g    "Read the input number as string and enter a while-do loop";
  __                     "Make 2 copies of the string number";
    W%:X                 "Reverse the second and store it in X";
        =                "Check if the number is already palindrome";
         0{      }?      "Put 0 on stack if it is palindrome, else, run the code block";
           ~             "Convert the string to int";
            X~           "Put the reverse string on stack and convert it to int too";
              +s         "Add the two numbers and covert back the result to string";
```

The core logic is that in each while-do iteration, you first check if palindrome is achieved or not. If not, add the reverse to the number. Pretty much what the algorithm is!

[Try it online here](http://cjam.aditsu.net/)

Answer (score 6):

This is an actual contender, since J has been around for decades.

## J (16 bytes)

```
(+^:~:|.&.":)^:_
```

This is a verb, so it can be assigned to a variable in a J session and used like so:

```
   f =. (+^:~:|.&.":)^:_
   f 5280
23232
```

How it works:

```
(+^:~:|.&.":)^:_
 +^:~:           add if unequal
      |.&.":     reverse under string format
 +^:~:|.&.":     add reverse unless a palindrome
(           )^:_ repeat until unchanged
```

Answer (score 6):

## [05AB1E](http://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 7 bytes

Code:

```
[DÂQ#Â+
```

Explanation:

```
[        # Infinite loop.
 DÂ      # Duplicate and bifurcate (which duplicates it and reverses the duplicate).
   Q#    # If the number and the number reversed are equal, break.
     Â+  # Add the reversed number to the initial number.
```

Uses the **CP-1252** encoding. [Try it online!](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=W0TDglEjw4Ir&input=NTI4MA).

Comment: Could you explain a little more on the process of bifurcation?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ For example, on the stack is the string `hello`. The bifurcation will keep the original string, and pushes the string reversed. It's short for _duplicate and reverse_.

Comment: Oh, I see. Cool! Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Python: 66

```
n=input()
while 1:
 r=int(`n`[::-1])
 if n==r:break
 n+=r
print n
```

Answer (score 4):

Perl, 40 chars

```
$_=<>;$_+=$r while$_!=($r=reverse);print
```

Comment: I know this is a really old post but a few changes can reduce this to 26 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HYtBCsMwDATveodvbYlYWBCYvKUnHwImMU7a51fd9rKIGc1oszOzPG9rqa/92nqp62zvNs92X0pdMsFwQ1DjQaMHTAhiTgvCLSDL0EVBjYfpQxb@KxBqqeFfEMocn2Nc27Gf@Rj9Cw "Perl 5 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 4):

## PHP - <s>54</s> 48 characters

```
<?for($s=`cat`;$s!=$r=strrev($s);$s+=$r);echo$s;
```

Test:

```
$ php 196.php <<< 5280
23232
```

Comment: I'm going to have to remember the `$str = `cat`` thing for future golfing.  Heck of a lot better than using `STDIN` and still better than `$argv[0]`.

Comment: @GigaWatt: _$s='m4'_ should also work.

Answer (score 4):

#### Scala 82

```
def p(n:Int):Int={val s=n.toString.reverse.toInt
if(n==s)n else p(n+s)}
p(readInt)
```

Answer (score 4):

## [JAGL](http://github.com/globby/jagl) Alpha 1.2 - 19, 21 with stdin

***Not contending***, just getting some experience with my language
Expects a number from stdin

```
T~d{DddgCi+dgdC=n}uSP
```

Explanation

```
T~                       Get a line of input, and eval to an integer
  d                      Duplicate (for first round)
   {Ddd                  Drop last and duplicate twice
       gCi               Convert to string, reverse, and convert back to integer
          +d             Add to original and duplicate
            gdC          Convert to string, duplicate, reverse
               =n}       If it isn't a palindrome, keep going
                  uSP    Run until palindrome reached, then print output number
```

Comment: Edited. @Optimizer

Comment: Please don't edit all your submissions at once for minor edits (like a version number), as this unnecessarily clutters the front page. It's fine if you do 2 or maybe 3 at a time, but please wait a few hours before doing more systematic edits.

Comment: Forgot that it would push to front page, my bad. @MartinBüttner

Answer (score 4):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 8 bytes

```
↔?|↔;?+↰
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SypKTM6ozMlPN/r//1HbFPsaIGFtr/2obcP//6ZGFgb/owA)

Somewhat similar to one of the first Brachylog programs I saw and was intrigued by, from the [Brachylog introduction video](https://youtube.com/watch?v=XYVhZ-MFcUs).

```
?↔?.|↔;?+↰.  (initial ? and the .s are implicit)

?↔?          % If the input and its reverse are the same,
   .         %   then the input is the output
    |↔;?+↰   % Or, add the input and its reverse, and call this predicate recursively
          .  % The result of that is the output
```

Answer (score 3):

### In Q (39 characters)

```
f:{while[x<>g:"I"$reverse -3!x;x+:g];x}
```

Sample Usage:

```
q)f 5280
23232
```

Edit:

Down to 34 now, same usage:

```
{while[x<>g:"I"$(|) -3!x;x+:g];x} 5280
```

Answer (score 3):

### C# - <strike>103</strike> 99 chars

```
public int P(int i)
{
    var r = int.Parse(new string(i.ToString().Reverse().ToArray())));
    return r == i ? i : P(i + r);        
}
```

C# never does very well in golf. Elegant, but verbose.

Comment: You can easily golf it more. Use ""+ rather than .ToString and get rid of some spaces.

Answer (score 3):

### Bash (64)

```
X=`rev<<<$1|sed s/^0*//`;[ $1 = $X ]&&echo $1||. $0 $(($1+$X))
```

Call with: bash <filename> <number>

Comment: What is the <filename> for?

Comment: @Eelvex the script needs to call itself so you need to store it in a file.

Answer (score 3):

```
r=input()
while 1:
    r=`r`
    if r==r[::-1]:
      break
    else:
      r=int(r)+int(r[::-1])

print r
```

Comment: Please leave what language you used and how many bytes it has; although I recognized it written in Python 2.

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 9 bytes (non competing)

A very simple answer, just for the challenge of coding in and esoteric language.

`ṚḌ+µŒḂ¬$¿`

```
ṚḌ        : take the argument, reverse (and vectorize) it
  +µ      : add both
    ŒḂ¬$¿ : while the result isn't a palindrome
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASEA3v9qZWxsef//4bma4biMK8K1xZLhuILCrCTCv////zUyODA)

Should this answer be unclear or wrong on any level, feel free to point it out.

Thanks to Dennis for helping me out with this first small piece of code.

Comment: Wow, not everyone uses Jelly in their first post.

Comment: It was on my to-do list to post an answer on PPCG using an esoteric language. Jelly happened to be the first one I thought of :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Java (JDK)](http://jdk.java.net/), <s>78</s> 71 bytes

```java
i->{for(int r=0,t;i!=r;)for(t=i+=r,r=0;t>0;t/=10)r=r*10+t%10;return i;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NY6xasNADIZn31OoQ8HXJO45UAgcF5qlkKFTxtJBdeygxDkHnWwowc/uyqUVSKCPn5/vjAOuzsfLVLWYErwjRbib17c@VkJdxHYfpeYGq9pkN6YBpQb6R7DXbJbpD00@X7TeZKM3BnSSoFClmR2EiVbbe9Pxb4qDW4qnh8DezkwCLQIvFXvZ6j6H0lkO/FS6hTyWznMtPUcgP07e3PqvVmv/2oeOjnBV6/wgTPH08QnIp2RVbHY4fCepr0XXS6H2UdqY74omf1lvnFVXgNGM0w8)

-7 Thanks to Celingcat!

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf! Nice first answer.

Comment: Thanks :D A friend showed me https://code.golf/ and I've been loving it since. first submission on this forum.

Answer (score 2):

Python. 85 characters:

```
s,i=str,int;rs=lambda q:s(q)[::-1];n=i(input());
while rs(n)!=s(n):n+=i(rs(n));print n
```

If you don't want output on each iteration:

```
s,i=str,int;rs=lambda q:s(q)[::-1];n=i(input());
while rs(n)!=s(n):n+=i(rs(n))
print n
```

(one less character)

Comment: The task description states that only the final palindrome should be printed.

Answer (score 2):

#### Windows PowerShell (63)

```
for($a=+"$input";-join"$a"[99..0]-ne$a){$a+=-join"$a"[99..0]}$a
```

I still hate it that there is no easy way to reverse a string.

Comment: Can be shortened by two characters if there only ever are ten digits of input. This way it's safe for `long` as well which is the largest integral type PowerShell supports anyway but still, I waste two chars.

Answer (score 2):

**Haskell <s>89</s> 87 chars**

```
r=read.reverse.show
main=getLine>>=print.head.filter(\x->x==r x).iterate(\x->x+r x).read
```

Somewhat readable version:

```
myFind p = head . filter p
rev = read . reverse . show
isPalindrome x = x == rev x
next x = x + rev x
sequence196 = iterate next
palindrome196 = myFind isPalindrome . sequence196

main = getLine >>= print . palindrome196 . read
```

The golfed version was created by manual inlining and renaming the remaining functions to single character names.

Comment: You can shorten this quite a bit by taking advantage of the underused function `until` from the Prelude, as well as extracting the pattern of applying a binary operator to `x` and `r x`. Also, use `readLn` instead of `getLine` and `read`. The result saves 20 characters: `f%x=f x$read.reverse.show$x;main=readLn>>=print.until((==)%)((+)%)`

Comment: @hammar: You could use the function monad and save even more: Define `r=(=<<read.reverse.show)` and just use ``r(==)`until`r(+)``. Apart from that saving, it doesn't need to be a full program, a valid submission could just be the unnamed function from before. This brings you down to 41 bytes: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyfmfZhvzv0jD1lYzoTSvJDMnoUhDW5OryFbD1samKDUxRa8otSy1qDhVrzgjv1zzf25iZp6CrUJBUWZeiYKKQpqCqZGFwf9/yWk5ienF/3UjnAMCAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

### befunge, 57 bytes

```
"KCTS"4(&:0\v
\T\a*+\:0`jv>:a%\a/
0:+_v#-TD2$<^\
  @.<
```

though the code is places in a 4x19 grid, so might call it 76.

- first line is initializeing, and reading input number
- second line reverse first number in stack and put it in the second stack position.
- and the third line checks if a number is palindrome.

Answer (score 2):

### C++ TMP (256 characters)

```
#include<cstdio>
#define Y(A,B,C,D)template<int N>struct A<C,D>{enum{v=B};};
#define Z(A)template<int N,int M>struct A{enum{v=
#define n 5194
Z(R)R<N/10,M*10+N%10>::v};};Y(R,N,0,N)Z(S)S<N+M,R<N+M,0>::v>::v};};Y(S,N,N,N)main(){printf("%d",S<n+R<n,0>::v,0>::v);}
```

This version could be shortened a bit, but a 256-character answer is hard to pass up. Here's an un-golfed version:

```
#include <iostream>

template<size_t N>
class Reverse
{
    template<size_t M, size_t R>
    struct Inner
    {
        enum { value = Inner<M/10, R*10 + M%10>::value };
    };

    template<size_t R>
    struct Inner<0, R>
    {
        enum { value = R };
    };

public:
    enum { value = Inner<N, 0>::value };
};

template<size_t N>
class OneNineSix
{
    template<size_t M, size_t R=Reverse<M>::value>
    struct Inner
    {
        enum { value = OneNineSix<M + R>::value };
    };

    template<size_t M>
    struct Inner<M, M>
    {
        enum { value = M };
    };

public:
    enum { value = Inner<N + Reverse<N>::value>::value };
};

int main()
{
    const size_t N = 4123;

    std::cout << OneNineSix<N>::value << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

### Pyke, 13 bytes (noncompeting)

```
D`_b]D$XIsr)h
```

[Try it here!](http://pyke.catbus.co.uk/?code=D%60_b%5DD%24XIsr%29h&input=89&warnings=0)

```
 `_b          -     int(reversed(str(num))
D   ]         -    [num, ^]
     D        -   _ = ^
      $       -  delta(^)
       XI     - if ^:
         s    -  num = sum(_)
          r   -  goto_start()
            h - _[0]
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Add++](https://github.com/cairdcoinheringaahing/AddPlusPlus), 57 bytes

```
L,BDbRBv
D,f,@,1]A+
D,g,@,1]A=
D,h,@,{f}A{g}Q{h}
L,{h}2/i
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0xJKSj4/99Hx8klKcipjMtFJ03HQccw1lEbyEyHMG2BzAwgszqt1rE6vTawOqOWy0cHSBrpZ/5XyUnMTUpJVDCys@fy///f1MjCAAA)

### How it works

```
L,	; Create a function 'lambda 1'
	; Example argument:   [5280]
    BD	; Digits;     STACK = [[5 2 8 0]]
    bR	; Reverse;    STACK = [[0 8 2 5]]
    Bv	; Undigits;   STACK = [825]

D,f,@,	; Define a monadic function 'f'
	; Example argument:         [5280]
    1]	; Call 'lambda 1';  STACK = [825]
    A+	; Add the argument; STACK = [6105]

D,g,@,	; Define a monadic function 'g'
	; Example argument:          [5280]
    1]	; Call 'lambda 1';   STACK = [825]
    A=	; Equal to argument; STACK = [0]

D,h,@,	; Define a monadic function 'h'
	; Example argument:  [5280]
   {f}	; Call 'f';  STACK = [6105]
   A{g}	; If 'g'...
   Q	;   Return
   {h}	; Else call 'h'

L,	; Define a function, 'lambda 2'
	; Example argument: [5280]
   {h}	; Call 'h'; STACK = [46464]
   2/i	; Halve;    STACK = [23232]
```

Answer (score 2):

## C (gcc), 132 bytes

```c
t;r(char*s){char*e=s+strlen(s)-1;for(;e>s;*e--=*s,*s++=t)t=*e;}g(o,l,f){for(l=malloc(9);sprintf(l,"%d",o),r(l),f=atoi(l),f-o;)o+=f;}
```

Call with `g(n)` for an `int n`. Try it online [here](https://tio.run/##bYvLCsIwFETX@hWlIOTmAdoqKJf4JW5CTGohTSTJrvTbY1pcllnMwDmjxaB1KRkj0R8VaYJ5ayMTSzk640kCcUEbIkHzTEiNEJImThNjMkOW1OAykMAdtzCvmpOTci5o8gBM3zj6bInj7end8gC8cuBWqhzGbYmAEJi0uJRqNpMaPYFmPh7@z/p7@ZY3A7l19zMA7pC@76/7pOtrVrSUHw).

Ungolfed:

```c
t; // temporary varaiable fpr swapping characters
r(char *s) { // helper function to reverse a string: takes a string argument and modifies it
    char *e = s + strlen(s) - 1; // find the end of the string
    for(; e > s; // move the end pointer and the start pointer towards each other until they meet
        *e-- = *s, *s++ = t) // swap the characters under the start and end pointers ...
        t = *e; // ... using the temporary variable
}
g(o, // function for the 196 algorithm: takes an int argument and returns an int
  l, f) { // abusing the argument list to declare to extra variables: one is a string for reversing the number, the other is an int
    for(l = malloc(9); // allocate space for the string
        sprintf(l, "%d", o), // convert the number to a string
        r(l), // reverse that string
        f = atoi(l), // convert it back to an int
        f - o; ) // loop until the two numbers are equal
        o += f; // add the two numbers
}
```

Comment: [119 bytes](https://tio.run/##bYvNCoMwEITP7VOIUNjVBMS0UFjSF@kPSExswCYl8VAQn92moUcZmBn4ZhQflFrX8SruFEA9u1BFnHNqaV2vPxBZg2R8AOJcXyJhpR@yinWdPDdaBvDM4JxH8R2smwyMrDz0JfPIAozIjOwmb3PjntDX0tCypmXx6qwDLOb97v9Mv5srWTHAqT03iLRBhBDHbdKKpB9a1i8 "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 2):

## GNU dc, 46 bytes

Requires GNU dc, min version 1.4 (for `R` command).

```dc
[O~3RO*+rd0<R]sR[+lfx]sg[ddO~rd0<R+d3R!=g]dsfx
```

Input and output are top-of-stack, as usual.  It takes a surprising amount of code to reverse digits in dc (unless I'm missing something, which is far from impossible).  It does have the numeric range to behave nicely with inputs such as these (which will overflow 32-bit unsigned arithmetic, for example):

- 89 ⇒ 8,813,200,023,188
- 8997 ⇒ 16,668,488,486,661
- 10677 ⇒ 4,668,731,596,684,224,866,951,378,664

#### Explanation

```dc
# Reverse digits, starting after first digit extracted
[O~3RO*+r d0<R]sR

# Recursion helper - add and recurse
[+ lfx]sg

# Main recursive function
[dd O~r d0<R+ d3R !=g]dsfx
```

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0n@b2hgZm7@P9q/zjjIX0u7KMXAJii2OChaOyetIrY4PTolxb8OLKidYhykaJsem1KcVvG/4D8A "dc – Try It Online") (Javascript)

Comment: Might want to specify that this works only on GNU dc 1.4 and later, since it uses the new `R` command. Good solution, though!

Comment: I'm working on a totally different approach but not sure it will wind up smaller.

Comment: Thanks Sophia - I hadn't realised that `R` was new.  Looking forward to seeing your method!

Comment: Ah, nope...I tried a different approach to arranging the outside loop but it ended up about five bytes larger and no prettier. You win. =)

Answer (score 2):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>193</s> <s>109</s> 105 bytes

-84 bytes thanks to Giuseppe! -4 byes thanks to JayCe!

```r
function(x){"-"=utf8ToInt
S=strtoi
"!"=rev
while({z=paste(S(x)+S(intToUtf8(!-x),10));any(-z!=!-z)})x=z
z}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DctBCsIwEADAe36RPe2igSoIBd0HeE59QJEEA5JIuq0xpW@Pnfvk5m@m@Tk@JaSIhVYwwLP4fkj3KMryJFlSUKCBs1vU9xXeDtfKn3ESh3YvB4shypAe@0JtCh1PHdF1jD80VbM2lTYqXFXdmke4nPsOqP0B)

Comment: You can (and should) choose a different way of doing this than string manipulation, but here are some golfing tips for the method you've chosen: `strsplit(x,"")` is shorter than `strsplit(x,NULL)`, and `el(L)` is shorter than `L[[1]]`. `as.double` is shorter than `as.numeric` and `strtoi` is shorter than both; instead of setting `t` just use it directly in your `if` statement. also this is a recursive function if I'm not mistaken, so you need to put `f=` as part of your submission.

Comment: @Giuseppe Got it. Thanks for the tips. I'll keep working on this. It's easier for me to just get something that works then go back and optimize.

Comment: Hehehe, no worries. If you're hell-bent on using strings (or forced to by the problem), consider `utf8ToInt` to convert to digits and `intToUtf8` to convert back. That'll be a big byte saving!

Comment: [Here is a 109 bytes golf using utf8ToInt and a `while` loop](https://tio.run/##JYpLCsIwEED3uYVdzaBCFYSCzgFcpzlAkQQDkkg6rXVKzx4HXL5PqeF2rGFKD445wYKro4lD1@d7YmNp5MI5ms8zvjysQu9hZA9Wx72FmLjPTm8ofganEvFwahGvQ/oqC@7oX0TLhguJka0GaC7nrm2w/gA)

Comment: @Giuseppe That is very helpful. I was running into issues with trying to add the two `utf8ToInt` converted numbers. Funny enough, using a recursive function instead of a `while` loop results in [108 byes](https://tio.run/##JYpBCoMwEADv/YWedqkHKwiC7AN6jrkrxYVcNhJXaVP69nRLTwMzkwpT4UMeGqLAE9@eDuVhinfR0dGuSWO4ZNqWXVdwdlwdBNEpetsgrSd4k4jNrUUc58AzLPIymbGif86/zIYm46cw1H03tDWWLw) assuming I don't have to put `f=`. Were you able to figure out if that was allowed?

Comment: You must use `f=` if it is recursive, unfortunately.

Comment: [Save 4 more bytes](https://tio.run/##DctBCsIwEADAe36RPe2igSoIBd0HeE59QJEEA5JIuq0xpW@Pnfvk5m@m@Tk@JaSIhVYwwLP4fkj3KMryJFlSUKCBs1vU9xXeDtfKn3ESh3YvB4shypAe@0JtCh1PHdF1jD80VbM2lTYqXFXdmke4nPsOqP0B) by using `-` in place of `U`. I also replaced `rev` with `!` but it does not save any byte...

Comment: @JayCe Interesting way to save bytes. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Powershell, <s>63</s> 62 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @AdmBorkBork*

```
param($m)for(;$m-$s;$m=-join"$s"[-1..-"$s".Length]){$s+=$m};$s
```

Test script:

```
$f = {
param($m)for(;$m-$s;$m=-join"$s"[-1..-"$s".Length]){$s+=$m};$s
}

&$f 5280
```

Comment: You don't need the `;` between `param($m)` and `for`.

Answer (score 2):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2), 7 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
(ḲQ;ḲN+
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m728JKM0Ly_faMGCpaUlaboWqzUe7tgUaA0k_LSXFCclF0PFFywxNbIwgLAB)

##### Explanation

```python
(ḲQ;ḲN+  # implicit input
(  ;     # while loop
  Q      # (condition)  not equal to
 Ḳ       #              its reverse
     N+  # (body)       add
    Ḳ    #              the reverse
         # implicit output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 17 bytes

```
{⍵+⍎⌽⍕⍵}⍣{⍺≡⍎⌽⍕⍺}
```

`{⍵+⍎⌽⍕⍵}` add argument and its reverse...
`⍣` ... until...
`{⍺≡⍎⌽⍕⍺}` ... the result is a palindrome.

Answer (score 1):

## Javascript ES6, 56 bytes

```
f=a=>(g=_=>[...""+a].reverse().join``)()==a?a:f(a+ +g())
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java, <s>90</s> 84 bytes

```java
n->{for(long t;(t=new Long(new StringBuffer(n+"").reverse()+""))!=n;)n+=t;return n;}
```

-6 bytes thanks to *@O.O.Balance*.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##hU/BCsIwDL37FdFTizhEEZQyD57Vi0fxUGs2qjMdbTYR2bfPznkVCSR5ySPv5aprPXEl0vVya02hQ4CdtvQaAFhi9Jk2CPsOAhSOcjDiU0iqOGsGMQXWbA3sgSCFlibrV@Z8z2IlOCV8wDYi0TUH9pbyTZVl6AWNRyOZeKzRBxSyQ3KYkpI0Tll55MoTkGraTquszkWU@arVzl7gHp2K/uLxpGXv8vAMjPfEVZyUccMFCUqMWMyWU/kx/ZOyXP0hzOYx5Pfzpn0D)

**Explanation:**

```java
n->{           // Method with long as both parameter and return-type
  for(long t;  //  Temp-long, starting uninitialized
      (t=new Long(new StringBuffer(n+"").reverse()+""))
               //  Before every iteration, reverse the temp-long
      !=n;)    //  And loop as long as it's not equal to `n` yet
    n+=t;      //   Add this temp-long to the input
  return n;}   //  Return the modified input as result
```

Comment: 84 bytes: https://tio.run/##jY6xTgMxDIb3PoXplKg0QkVIReE6MDCVqSNiCNekypE6keMcqqp79iMHt4MsWbb/T9bXmd6sY7LYHT/HNpic4dV4vC4AMhv2LXSVUIV9UK5gyz6iepmHp33E0y1MfQcOmhHXu6uLJEK9AGlBDdqvn1xMw4HJ4@m5OGdJ4Gq5lIpsbylbIadN3jSoJa4a0mS5EALqYdTVJZWPUF1mpT76I5yrpvj9@PZu5GQMcLhktmcVC6tUEw4onDIphYt42Gzv9lLqv7jt43@ozX2tGRwWw/gN

Answer (score 1):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), <s>11</s> 10 [bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1)

```
@¶ìw}a@±ìw
```

[Try it](https://petershaggynoble.github.io/Japt-Interpreter/?v=1.4.6&code=QLbsd31hQLHsdw&input=NTI4MA)

```
@¶ìw}a@±ìw     :Implicit input of integer U
@              :Left function
 ¶             :  Test U for equality with
  ì            :  Convert to digit array
   w           :    Reverse and convert back to integer
    }          :End function
     a         :Get the first result of the right function that returns true when run through the left function
      @        :Right function
       ±       :  Increment U by
        ìw     :  As above
```

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 57 Bytes

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MU0jRU8jSrU5Mz8jWKS4qKUstAfEVbIGGfhiSiDcRWKnnWtf/TNEyNLAw0rblAehSUYvKUrLnSNMwMDUzRxSwsNa3/AwA)

**Code, recursive function**

```
function f($n){echo(strrev($n)!=$n)?f(strrev($n)+$n):$n;}
```

**Explanation**

```
function f($n){
    echo(strrev($n)!=$n)? #check if non-palindrome
        f(strrev($n)+$n): #true, call again with $n + reverse $n
        $n;               #false (is a palindrome) echo $n

}
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](https://github.com/nxadm/rakudo-pkg), 36 bytes

```perl6
{($_,{$_+.flip}...{$_==.flip})[*-1]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1upoJamYKvwv1pDJV6nWiVeWy8tJ7OgVk9PD8ixtYXwNKO1dA1ja/8XJ1YqpGmYGlkYaFpzQTgWlnCmkTEQalr/BwA)

An anonymous code block that returns the last element of a sequence defined by:

- The first element is the first parameter
- The `i+1`th element is the `i`th element plus the reverse of itself
- And ends when the element is equal to its reverse

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, 18 bytes

```
`Vt2&P=?5M.}1MvUsT
```

[Try it on MATL Online](https://matl.io/?code=%60Vt2%26P%3D%3F5M.%7D1MvUsT&inputs=5280&version=20.9.2)

```
         % (implicit input)
`        % do-while loop
  Vt     % convert the number into a string, duplicate it
  2&P    % flip the copy left-to-right
  =      % are they equal? 
    ?5M. % if yes, push the number back on the stack and exit
         % (implicit output display)
    }1M  % else, push the number and its reverse (as strings) again on to the stack
    vUs  % convert them to numbers and add them
    T    % "True" value to continue loop, this time with the sum as the input number
         % (implicit loop end)
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), 7 bytes

```
¤Ω`S↔=+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9CScysTgh@1TbHV/v//v6mRhQEA)

Alternatively we could use 
[`ΩS=↔S+↔`](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//9zKYNtHbVOCtYHE////TY0sDAA) for the same amount of bytes, but I like the one above more.

### Explanation

```
¤Ω`S↔=+
¤        -- compose the arguments of
 Ω       -- | iterate second function until first is truthy
         -- with
  `S     -- | flipped S: applying binary function to itself and
    ↔    -- | | itself reversed
         -- first function: check if palindrome (\x-> x == reverse x)
         -- second function: "196ify" (\x-> x + reverse x)
```

Answer (score 1):

## Ruby, 55 bytes

```
l=->x{x.reverse==x ? x:l[(x.to_i+x.reverse.to_i).to_s]}
```

Different approach than the other Ruby one, ended up golfing it down to one byte fewer

Explanation: makes a lambda `l` that recursively calls itself, each time adding the number's reverse, until the string is a palindrome

Slightly less golfed version:

```
func = ->x do
  (x.reverse == x) ? x : func[(x.to_i + x.reverse.to_i).to_s]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

## Excel VBA, 49 bytes

An immediate window function which takes input from range `[A1]` and outputs to the VBE immediate window.

```vb
n=[A1]:Do:n=n+r:r=StrReverse(n):Loop While n-r:?n
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua 5.3.3, 57 bytes

Takes `i` as input, prints output:

```
r=0while i~=r do i=i+r|0r=0+(i..""):reverse()end print(i)
```

More readable version:

```
r=0
while i~=r do
  i=i+r|0
  r=0+(i..""):reverse()
end
print(i)
```

Super simple. Just repeatedly adds `i` to its reverse until `i` is equal to its reverse. Then it just prints the new value of `i`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Actually](https://github.com/Mego/Seriously), 16 bytes

```
;WX;$R≈+;$;R=YWX
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S0wuKU3Myan8/986PMJaJehRZ4e2tYp1kG1keMT//6ZGFgYA)

Explanation:

```
;WX;$R≈+;$;R=YWX
;                 push a copy of n
 W            W   while top of stack is truthy:
  X                 pop and discard
   ;$R≈+            copy n, cast to string, reverse, cast to int, add
        ;$;R=Y      not palindrome (cast to string, copy, reverse, check inequality)
               X  pop and discard
```

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 27 bytes

```
(+&.".|.)^:(-.@-:|.)^:_&.":
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qvpKeepmBrpaCuoKNgoGAFxLp6Cs5BPm7/NbTV9JT0avQ046w0dPUcdK3AzHigoNV/Ta7U5Ix8BSNjIFSwVUhTMDWyMICIGRqCBQyhXGNjCNfoPwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 53 bytes

```python
f=lambda x,y=0:x if x==y else f(x+y,int(`x+y`[::-1]))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYtBCoMwFAX3PcVbJvgLiVIqgZxEhFjqpx9sFHWRnD7GzTCLmS2fvzW2pbBfpv/nOyFR9sYlCCN5nzEvxwxWqckk8VShShice9pR68LrDoFEDK@2NwRrKjpLePcEM7oHsO33xkpqfgE)

Answer (score 1):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), 47 bytes

```ruby
->a{v=a.to_s.reverse;v==a.to_s ? a:f[a+v.to_i]}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvyfZvtf1y6xusw2Ua8kP75Yryi1LLWoONW6zBYqomCvkGiVFp2oXQbiZsbW/i9QSIs2NovlAtGmRhYGEJaJoZGxuWHsfwA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 6 bytes

```
{Ḃ≠|m:
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%E1%B8%82%E2%89%A0%7Cm%3A&inputs=5280&header=&footer=)

Wooo cursed behaviour for numbers ftw.

### Explained

```
{Ḃ≠|m:
{Ḃ≠|      # while t.o.s[::-1] != tos:
    m     #     mirror the tos (that is, add the reverse of the number to the number)
     :    #     and duplicate the tos so that the while loop condition has a value to work on.
```

Comment: [Alternate 6 byter w/ flag](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=r&code=%E2%81%BDm%E2%80%A1%E1%B8%82%E2%89%A0%C4%BF&inputs=5280&header=&footer=)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 49 bytes

\$n\$ added to its reverse is \$2n\$ iff \$n\$ is a palindrome.

```python
f=lambda n,r=0:n-r*2and f(n+int(`n`[::-1]),n)or r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P802JzE3KSVRIU@nyNbAKk@3SMsoMS9FIU0jTzszr0QjIS8h2spK1zBWUydPM79Ioeh/QRFQHChvamRhoPkfAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Pyt](https://github.com/mudkip201/pyt), 10 bytes

```
`ΠĐ₫+Đ₽¬ł+
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gs@f8/4dyCIxMeNa3WBpF7D6052qT9/7@pkYUBAA)

```
`       ł          do... while top of stack is not 0
 Π                 product of everything on the stack (gets input on first pass;
                       otherwise removes the pesky 1 that resulted from the loop checking)
  Đ                Đuplicate 
   ₫               reverse the ₫igits
    +              add
     Đ             Đuplicate
      ₽¬           is the result not a ₽alindrome?
         +         add (removes the pesky 0 that was used to break out of the loop)
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Wren](https://github.com/munificent/wren), 102 bytes

A super long program.

```
Fn.new{|x|
while(x!=x[-1..0])x=(Num.fromString(x)+Num.fromString(x[-1..0])).toString
System.write(x)
}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Ky9KzftfllikkFaal6xgq/DfLU8vL7W8uqaihqs8IzMnVaNC0bYiWtdQT88gVrPCVsOvNFcvrSg/N7ikKDMvXaNCUxtdBKZYU68kHyLGFVxZXJKaq1delFkCNFCTq/Y/yDq95MScHA0lUyMLAyXN/wA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 7 bytes

```
{:Ḃ≠|Ḃ+
```

[Try it Online!](https://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%7B%3A%E1%B8%82%E2%89%A0%7C%E1%B8%82%2B&inputs=89&header=&footer=)

```
{       # While...
 :Ḃ≠    # It's not a palindrome
    |   # Do...
     Ḃ+ # Concatenate to its reverse
```

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 46 bytes

```javascript
f=n=>[r=``,...n+r].map(d=>r=d+r)|n-r?f(+r+n):n
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##BcFbCoAgEADA6yjmEkEQwdpBIkh8RGGrrNFXd7eZy762Oj7Loyn70FpEQrMy7nsHAKR4g9sW4dEwesXyI81LFIoVyZmay1RzCpDyIaIYh6mXsv0)

Answer (score 0):

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 12 bytes

```
|[st[~q]+~]0
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C%5Bst%5B%7Eq%5D%2B%7E%5D0&inputs=5280)

## Explanation

```
|              take input
 [ ....... ]0  infinite loop
   s           save top of stack to storage
    t          reverse this value
     [~ ]      execute if the reversed value is equal to the saved value
       q       quit the program, the result is printed implicitly
         +~    add the stored value to the current value
```

## [Rattle](https://github.com/DRH001/Rattle), 21 bytes (a different approach)

```
|[st+~s1/~[2g1/q]g1]0
```

[Try it Online!](https://www.drh001.com/rattle/?flags=&code=%7C%5Bst%2B%7Es1%2F%7E%5B2g1%2Fq%5Dg1%5D0&inputs=5280)

## Explanation

```
|                    take input
 [ ... ]0            infinite loop
 
  s                  save top of stack to storage in slot 0
   t                 reverse top of stack
    +~               add value in slot 0 to top of stack
      s1             save result in slot 1
        /~           divide this by the value in slot 0 (the previous number)
          
  [2 ... ]           if the result is exactly 2, execute code inside if statement
    g1               get value in slot 1
      /              divide (with no argument, divides by 2)
       q             quit program, top of stack is output implicitly
          g1         get value in slot 1
```