# Reverse and subtract

Tags: code-golf, number-theory

## Challenge description

Let's take a positive integer `n`, reverse its digits to get `rev(n)` and get the absolute value of the difference of these two numbers: `|n - rev(n)|` (or `abs(n - rev(n))`).

Example:

```
n = 5067 
rev(n) = 7605
|n - rev(n)| = |5067 - 7605| = |-2538| = 2538
```

After repeating this operation sufficiently many times, most numbers will become `0` (thus terminating the loop)...

```
5067 -> 2538 -> 5814 -> 1629 -> 7632 -> 5265 -> 360 -> 297 -> 495 -> 99 -> 0
```

...though some numbers (like `1584`) get stuck in an infinite loop:

```
1584 -> 3267 -> 4356 -> 2178 -> 6534 -> 2178 -> 6534 -> 2178 -> 6534 -> ...
                        ^ infinite loop starts here
```

Your job is to determine if a given integer gets stuck in an infinite loop.

## Input description

A positive integer.

## Output description

A truthy value (`True`, `1`) if the number gets stuck in an infinite loop, a falsy value (`False`, `0`) otherwise.

## Notes

- Trailing zeroes should be ommited. i.e. `rev(5020) = 205`.
- Remember that this is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so make your code as short as possible!
- Relevant sequence: [A072140](https://oeis.org/A072140)

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/159/8478) [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/51839/8478)

Comment: An interesting note: it is possible to construct an arbitrarily long integer with a looping period of 2, as described in the comments on [A072141](https://oeis.org/A072141). The method is identical for other periods as well, like 12, 14, 17, and 22.

Answer (score 18):

## Pyth, 5 bytes

4 bytes thanks to FryAmTheEggman

```
uas_`
```

[Test suite.](http://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=uas_%60&test_suite=1&test_suite_input=5067%0A1584&debug=0)

The truthy value is one of the numbers in the loop.

The falsey value is `0`.

### Explanation

```
uas_`      Input:Q
uas_`GGQ   Implicit filling of variables.

u      Q   Set G as Q: do this repeatedly until result seen before: Set G as
 a             the absolute difference of
     G             G
    `              convert to string
   _               reverse
  s                convert to integer
      G        and G
```

Comment: Nice use of the auto-fill variables!

Comment: *abuse – – – – –

Comment: How does that work, for someone that does not know Pyth?

Comment: @Fatalize Done.

Comment: how is pyth so short yet still in ASCII range ._.

Comment: @Downgoat Because it is pyth.

Answer (score 11):

### Mathematica, <s>39</s> 37 bytes

```
Nest[Abs[#-IntegerReverse@#]&,#,#]<1&
```

Simply applies the reverse/subtract transformation `n` times to the input `n` and then checks whether the result is `0`. It can never take more than `10n` steps to reach a loop, because the transformation cannot increase the number of digits, and there are less than `10n` numbers with no more digits than `n`. [See Dennis's proof for how to reduce this bound to `n`.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84126/8478)

Answer (score 11):

## [Jelly](http://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>6</s> 5 [bytes](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/wiki/Code-page)

```
ṚḌạµ¡
```

[Try it online!](http://jelly.tryitonline.net/#code=4bma4biM4bqhwrXCoQ&input=&args=NTA2Nw)

#### Background

This uses [@MartinEnder's upper bound](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84125) of **10n** iterations and the following observations.

1. There are **9 × 10<sup>k - 1</sup>** positive integers **n** with **k** digits.
2. The difference of a number and its reverse is always a multiple of **9**, so only **10<sup>k - 1</sup>** of them can occur after the first iteration.
3. Of the multiples, more than **1 / 10** will lose a digit in the next iteration (for starters, all that start and end with the same digits, and roughly twice as many if the first digit is neither a **1** nor a **9**), so it takes at most **9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup>** to either enter a loop or lose a digit.
4. Applying the same reasoning to the eventual resulting integer of **k - 1** digits and so on, it takes at most **9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup> + 9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup> + … ≤ 10<sup>k - 1</sup> ≤ n** iterations to enter a loop or reach **0**.

#### How it works

```
ṚḌạµ¡  Main link. Argument: n

   µ¡  Iteratively apply the chain to the left n times.
Ṛ      Reverse n (casts to digits).
 Ḍ     Undecimal; convert from base 10 to integer.
  ạ    Take the absolute difference of the result and the argument.
```

Comment: Did Pyth beat Jelly?

Comment: Well, it's a tie.

Comment: These ain't no bytes.

Comment: @mik Please click the *bytes* link in the header.

Answer (score 5):

## Oracle SQL 11.2, 136 bytes

```sql
WITH v(n)AS(SELECT :1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL SELECT ABS(n-REVERSE(n||''))FROM v WHERE n>0)CYCLE n SET c TO 0 DEFAULT 1 SELECT MIN(c)FROM v;
```

Un-golfed

```sql
WITH v(n) AS
(
  SELECT :1 FROM DUAL
  UNION ALL
  SELECT ABS(n-REVERSE(n||''))FROM v WHERE n>0 
) CYCLE n SET c TO 0 DEFAULT 1
SELECT MIN(c)FROM v
```

Answer (score 5):

### APL, 26 chars

```
0∘{⍵∊⍺:×⍵⋄(⍺,⍵)∇|⍵-⍎⌽⍕⍵}
```

We use the left argument as the accumulator of the values we've seen already. We initialise it to "0", which is one of the two termination conditions.
The guard `⍵∊⍺:×⍵` is read: "is the right argument something we've seen already (and that includes zero)? If so return the sign of the number, that is 1 or 0". Otherwise let's recurse by calling ourselves with the absolute value of the subtraction after having catenated the current value to the left argument.

A recast of the Mathematica solution by Martin Ender would clock at **21 chars**:

```
 {×{|⍵-⍎⌽⍕⍵}⍣(10×⍵)⊣⍵}
```

It reads: "what is the sign of the result after applying the wanted 10n times"?

Answer (score 4):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 13 bytes

```
ri_{_sW%i-z}*
```

[Test it here.](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri_%7B_sW%25i-z%7D*&input=5067)

Same as my Mathematica answer.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 2, 50 bytes

```python
n=input()
exec'n=abs(n-int(`n`[::-1]));'*n
print n
```

Test it on [Ideone](http://ideone.com/W9Bb1e).

#### Background

This uses [@MartinEnder's upper bound](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84125) of **10n** iterations and the following observations.

1. There are **9 × 10<sup>k - 1</sup>** positive integers **n** with **k** digits.
2. The difference of a number and its reverse is always a multiple of **9**, so only **10<sup>k - 1</sup>** of them can occur after the first iteration.
3. Of the multiples, more than **1 / 10** will lose a digit in the next iteration (for starters, all that start and end with the same digits, and roughly twice as many if the first digit is neither a **1** nor a **9**), so it takes at most **9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup>** to either enter a loop or lose a digit.
4. Applying the same reasoning to the eventual resulting integer of **k - 1** digits and so on, it takes at most **9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup> + 9 × 10<sup>k - 2</sup> + … ≤ 10<sup>k - 1</sup> ≤ n** iterations to enter a loop or reach **0**.

Answer (score 3):

### Python, <s>129</s> <s>120</s> 96 bytes

If a exception is caught (normally the only exception that can be throwed with this function is a RuntimeError, due to the infinite recursion), print 1. Otherwise, print the result, 0.

```python
def r(n):a=abs(n-int(str(n)[::-1]));return a and r(a)
try:print(r(int(input())))
except:print(1)
```

Thanks to @LeakyNun
Thanks to @shooqie

Comment: That's officially a (nice) abuse of infinite recursion.

Comment: `return a and rev(a)`

Comment: Isn't it possible to get a RuntimeError due to the recursion being very long without it being necessarily infinite?

Comment: `a=[n-x,x-n][n>x]`

Comment: You can shorten it drastically: `def rev(n):a=abs(n-int(str(n)[::-1]));return a and rev(a)`. Also, name the method something short (like `r` instead of `rev`)

Comment: @shooqie I have forgotten that `abs` is built-in ._.

Answer (score 3):

## Python, <s>101</s> 98 bytes

Tortoise and hare algorithm.

Truthy is any value in loop, falsey is `0`.

```python
g=lambda n:abs(n-int(str(n)[::-1]))
def r(n):
    t=g(n);h=g(t)
    while t-h:h=g(g(h));t=g(t)
    return h
```

[Ideone it!](http://ideone.com/fzXmzU)

Answer (score 3):

### Python 2, <s>85</s> <s>84</s> 83 bytes

```
L=[]
def f(n,L=L):
    if n<1or n in L:print n<1
    else:L+=[n];f(abs(n-int(`n`[::-1])))
```

Another Python answer. It adds n to a list for every iteration, and if n is already in the list, it outputs `False`. Otherwise, it works down to 0.

*Thanks @NonlinearFruit for one byte.*

Comment: I believe `print n<1` works (since `n` is always non-negative) and it saves a byte

Comment: `def f(n,L=[]):¶ if n<1or n in L:print n<1¶ else:f(abs(n-int(\`n\`[::-1])),L+[n])` saves 5 bytes

Answer (score 3):

### 05AB1E, <s>11</s> <s>8</s> 6 bytes

```
DFÂï-Ä
```

**Explained**

```
DF          # input number of times do
  Â         # push current number and its reverse
   ï-       # convert reverse to int and subtract
     Ä      # absolute value
            # implicitly print after loop ends
```

Truthy value is a number from the loop.
Falsy value is 0.

[Try it online](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=REbDgsOvLcOE&input=NTA2Nw)

Uses the upper bound explained in [Dennis' Jelly answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/84126/47066)

Saved 2 bytes thanks to @Adnan

In [version 7.9](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/7f7df2e8c4575ab0669f2129a48a7c2cc623b86b) of 05AB1E the following 5-byte solutions works as noted by @Adnan

```
DFÂ-Ä
```

Comment: Okay, this is a bit of a weird golf but `DFÂ-Ä` works in [version 7.9](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/tree/7f7df2e8c4575ab0669f2129a48a7c2cc623b86b) but not in the current version. In the current version, you need to convert it to an int first (like this `DFÂï-Ä`), but you can use version 7.9 to make it 5 bytes :p.

Comment: @Adnan I can't believe I forgot about the bifurcation function. I'll stick to the current version though. You could post the 7.9 one as a separate answer if you'd like. Otherwise I'll put it as a note.

Comment: I probably won't post it, since it's just 1 byte away from this answer :p.

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), <s>49</s> <s>32</s> 23 bytes

```
:10*N,?:N:{r:?-+.}itT'0
```

Returns `true` for infinite loops and `false` otherwise.

This is a shameless adaptation of Martin Ender's algorithm.

#### Previous answer, 32 bytes

```
g{tTr:T-+U(0!\;?:ImU;?:[U]c:1&)}
```

#### Explanation of the previous answer

```
g{                             } Call predicate with [Input] as input
  tT                             T is the last element of Input
    r:T-                         Subtract T from the reverse of T
        +U                       U is the absolute value of T
          (0!\                   If U is 0, return false
              ;                  Or
               ?:ImU             If U is in Input, return true
                    ;            Or
                     ?:[U]c:1&)  Recursive call with U concatenated to the Input
```

Answer (score 1):

## Java 7, 161 bytes

This requires an import but I wrote it as a function. Yell at me in the comments if a full program is preferred in this scenario. Outputs 1 if there's an infinite loop and 0 if the value gets to 0.

```
import java.util.*;int z(int a){int o,r,c=a;Set s=new HashSet();while(c!=0){for(r=0,o=c;o!=0;r=r*10+o%10,o/=10);c=Math.abs(c-r);if(!s.add(c))return 1;}return 0;}
```

Comment: Noting that I've seen imports and functions done before. [example](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/51840/51785)

Comment: Is `1` truthy ?

Comment: @LeakyNun 1 isn't considered truthy in java but OP lists (True,1) and (False,0) as acceptable outputs.

Comment: @LeakyNun Does Java even have a sense of truthy or falsy?

Comment: @Neil Java has a sense of leveraging synergistic opportunities in vertical market contexts -- that's it

Answer (score 0):

### PowerShell v2+, 94 bytes

```
param($n)for($a=,0;){if(($n=[math]::Abs($n-(-join"$n"["$n".length..0])))-in$a){$n;exit}$a+=$n}
```

Takes input `$n`, starts an infinite `for` loop, with `$a=,0` as the initial condition (this uses the comma operator to set `$a` to an array of one element, `0`). This `$a` is our array of already-seen values.

Each loop iteration we check an `if`. The condition first sets the next value of `$n` using string-reversing and the `[math]::Abs` .NET call, and checks whether that value is already `-in` `$a`. If so, we output `$n` and `exit`. Otherwise, we add that value to the array and continue the loop.

Outputs `0` for input values where it does not go into an infinite loop (which is falsey in PowerShell) and outputs the value where the loop was encountered otherwise (non-zero integers are truthy). For example, outputs `2178` for input `1584`.

Answer (score 0):

### Haskell, 65 bytes

```
_#0=0
a#n|elem n a=1|1<2=(n:a)#abs(n-(read$reverse$show n))
([]#)
```

Returns `0` for False and `1` for True. Usage example: `([]#) 1584` -> `1`.

The obvious approach: keep a list with all results seen so far. Calculate the next number until `0` or it's in the list.

Answer (score 0):

### JavaScript (ES6), 75 bytes

```
f=(n,...a)=>a.includes(n=n<0?-n:n)?n:f([...n+``].reverse().join``-n,n,...a)
```

`n<0?n=-n:n` and `n*=n>0||-1` also work. Algorithm somewhat resembles the PowerShell answer, although this is a recursive formulation.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 57 bytes

```
->n,*h{h[n]=n=(n-"#{n}".reverse.to_i).abs until h[n];n>0}
```

The initially empty array `h` tracks previously hit values. We iterate the number until we hit a previous value, then check the value on the last iteration. Since 0 is a cycle of 1, it'll be 0 if and only if there's no larger cycle. I take an extra 2 bytes to convert this to a Boolean because 0 is truthy in Ruby.

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org)  <s>58 53 33</s>  30 bytes

```perl6
sub {$/=%;$^a,{return ?1 if $/{$_}++;abs $_-.flip}...0;?0}
{$/=%;?($_,{last if $/{$_}++;abs $_-.flip}...0)[*-1]}
{?($_,{abs $_-.flip}...0)[10**$_]}

{?($_,{abs $_-.flip}...0)[$_]}
```

#### Explanation:

```perl6
{ # block lambda with implicit parameter $_

  # coerce the following to Bool
  # ( False for Nil or 0, True otherwise )
  ?

  (

    $_, # start a sequence with the input

    # block lambda with implicit parameter $_
    # subtracts the previous value in the sequence and its reverse
    # ( .flip is short for $_.flip where a term is expected )
    { abs $_ - .flip } 

    ... # repeat that lambda
    0   # until you get 0

  # get the element indexed with the block's input
  # may be 0, Nil, or a number that is part of a repeating sequence
  )[ $_ ]
}
```

( relies on the previous observation that you only need to do this transformation at most `n` times )

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/) `-p`, 25 bytes

```perl
eval'$_=abs$_-reverse'x$_
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z@1LDFHXSXeNjGpWCVetyi1LLWoOFW9QiX@/39TAzNzLkNTC5N/@QUlmfl5xf91C/7r5gAA)

It iterates `n=|n-rev(n)|` n times, so output is 0 if there is no loop, >0 otherwise. Dennis already proved this is enough.

Comment: Nice answer, and welcome to PPCG! Note that for Perl, command-line options [must be included](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/274/42963) in your byte-count, so this isn't *quite* 30 bytes.

Comment: @TimmyD ok, +1 for `-p` option, `-l` is not necessary for a single input

Comment: changed according to new [flag rules](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14339/55918)

Answer (score 0):

### Matlab, <s>89</s> 84 bytes

```
n=input('');z=n;while n
z=abs(z-str2num(fliplr(num2str(z))));n=[n z]*all(n~=z);end
z
```

Simple approach - stacks all numbers and checks if a number appeared before.

**Explanation**

```
n=input('');z=n;  -- take input, initiate z
while n           -- n is said to be positive
z=abs(z-str2num(fliplr(num2str(z)))) -- calculate the "reverse and substract"
n=[n z]           -- put the value at the end of the vector
       *all(n~=z) -- make the n all zeroes if z is previously in the vector (break the loop)
end
z                 -- print z (0 when not entered loop, >0 otherwise)
```