# Adding up the digits and the digits reversed

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

Given a number > 0, output the sum with all digits (1 .. n) concatenated and reversed and add them up. For example, with n = 6:

The numbers 1 to 6 concatenated:

```
123456
```

Reversed:

```
654321
```

Adding them up together will result in: 777777. Another example is n = 11:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 > 1234567891011
```

and

```
11 10 9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 > 1110987654321
```

Adding them up together will result in `2345555545332`. This is also known as [A078262](https://oeis.org/A078262).

Shortest code wins!

Comment: [Related.](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/159/196-algorithm-code-golf)

Comment: Is there a bound to `n`, or do we have to support arbitrarily large integers?

Comment: I think the default is "bounded by `max(256,yourlanguagesdefaultintegertypelimit)`". But it should be specified.

Comment: @LegionMammal978 As high as your language supports.

Comment: Important test case: `10`, which should give `23333333231`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

## 05AB1E, 7 bytes

```
LDRJsJ+
```

[Try it online.](http://05ab1e.tryitonline.net/#code=TERSSnNKKw&input=Ng)

### Explanation

```
LDRJsJ+

L        range from 1 .. input
 D       duplicate
  R      reverse
   JsJ   convert both arrays to strings
      +  add (coerces both strings to ints)
```

Comment: I feel very confused by the design choice that lead to `+` on lists doing a nested addition, while for strings it converts to ints and then adds. But I guess it worked out here! :P

Comment: @FryAmTheEggman I'm going to remove nested addition though. It has never been useful since the moment I've implemented it...

Comment: Sheesh, I leave PPCG for two hours and you rename yourself Aqua Tart while I'm gone... Oh, the life of a PPCG user.

Answer (score 7):

## Jelly, 9 bytes

```
R,U$DF€ḌS
```

[image: livecoding]

Comment: Is it me or do I see that code secretly stealing some U$D?

Comment: [-3 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z9IJ1QlLPj/4fZHTWuOTnq4c8b//2Y6CoaGAA)

Answer (score 5):

### CJam, <s>15</s> 14 bytes

Thanks to Martin for shaving a byte!

```
ri,:)_W%si\si+
```

[Try it online!](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=ri%2C%3A)_W%25si%5Csi%2B&input=11)

Comment: 1 byte less if you flip the string instead of the numeric array: `ri,:)s_W%i\i+`

Comment: Sorry, I think my version doesn't work for `10`

Comment: This code is secretly happy. `:)`

Answer (score 4):

### Pyth, <s>12</s> 10 bytes

```
ssMjLk_BSQ
```

Thanks to [@FryAmTheEggman](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/31625/fryamtheeggman) for 2 bytes!

`Q` is the input, `S` turns it into `[1, 2, ..., input()]`, `_B` bifurcates it over `_` (reverse) to create `[rng, rev(rng)]`, `jLk` maps it over `join` by `k` (which is the "empty string" variable), `sM` maps `int` over *this* resulting array, and `s` finally calculates the sum.

Answer (score 4):

## Python 3, 74

Saved 6 bytes thanks to DSM.

Nothing too exciting, join the ranges and then convert to ints and add them.

```
lambda x:sum(int(''.join(list(map(str,range(1,x+1)))[::i]))for i in(1,-1))
```

Comment: [71 bytes](https://tio.run/##NcxBDoMgEIXhvaeYnTMVm2B3JJ5EXWBaKo0MBDHR01NcuPxfvrxwpsXzK5t@zKt281vDobbdoeWEdf38ecs4PJwOuKUooubvB6U4Gkk0DUrZicj4CBaKk6Itc76aS8OtZUeqghCvTxZgkIv6Aw)

Answer (score 4):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>70</s> <s>67</s> 64 bytes

```js
a=>(z=[...Array(a)].map((b,c)=>c+1)).join``- -z.reverse().join``
```

Fixed to meet requirement, as old code was made under misunderstanding of the input.

Comment: @TimmyD Added an explanation.

Comment: @TimmyD OH! >_< My misunderstanding of the challenge is how... Yeah, I'll have to fix this.

Comment: @TimmyD Took me long enough to get back online. It's fixed now, and thanks for catching that.

Comment: As noted for another answer, this only works if the parameter a is between 1 and 12, that's really too little

Comment: @edc65 [Per OP's comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/73867/adding-up-the-digits-and-the-digits-reversed/73878?noredirect=1#comment179233_73867), that's big enough.

Answer (score 3):

## [Retina](https://github.com/mbuettner/retina), 71

- 7 bytes saved thanks to @daavko.
- 3 bytes saved thanks to [version 0.7.3 features](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/27728253#27728253)

Because its blatantly the wrong tool for the job.

```
.+
$*a:$&$*
+`^(a+)a\b(.*)\b1(1+)$
$1 $& $3
 ?(\w)+ ?
$#1
\d+:?
$&$*c
c
```

[Try it online.](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=LisKJCphOiQmJCoKK2BeKGErKWFcYiguKilcYjEoMSspJAokMSAkJiAkMwogPyhcdykrID8KJCMxClxkKzo_CiQmJCpjCmM&input=Ng)

Works for inputs up to 6, but the online interpreter times out after that.

Comment: You can shorten it to 74 by removing the last line and changing `(c)+` to `c`.

Comment: @daavko yes, of course, thanks!

Comment: Also, `$&$*c` -> `$*c` and `\d+:?` -> `\d+` and it's 70. And for some reason it keeps working...

Answer (score 3):

### JavaScript (ES6), <s>67</s> 66 bytes

```
n=>(a=[...Array(n+1).keys()].slice(1)).join``- -a.reverse().join``
```

Yes, that's a space. Ugh. At least @Downgoat helped me save a byte.

Comment: You can remove the first `+` and make the `+ +` -> `- -` to save a byte

Comment: n=>(a=[...Array(n)].map(_=>n--)).join``- -a.reverse().join``

Comment: Note: using simple js arithmetic this is limited to values 1 .. 12

Answer (score 3):

## Jolf, 9 bytes

[Try it here!](http://conorobrien-foxx.github.io/Jolf/#code=K1AQzrN6alBfzrM) Replace `►` with `\x10`.

```
+P►γzjP_γ
    zj    range 1...j
   γ      γ = ^
  ►        ^ .join("")
 P         as a number
+     P_γ  and γ reversed
```

I *may* be able to golf it by moving around the type casting.

Comment: You beat pyth and doorknob!

Comment: @Cyoce so I did O_O

Answer (score 3):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Lyxal/Vyxal) `s`, 5 bytes

```
ɾḂWvṅ
```

[Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=s&code=%C9%BE%E1%B8%82Wv%E1%B9%85&inputs=11&header=&footer=)

```
ɾ         range: [1 .. x]
 Ḃ        pop x, push x, reversed(x) [bifurcate]
  W       wrap the stack
   v      for each
    ṅ     join on ""

s (flag)  sum
```

-2 bytes thanks to Razetime

Comment: -1: [Try it Online!](http://lyxal.pythonanywhere.com?flags=&code=%C9%BE%E1%B8%82Wv%E1%B9%85%E2%88%91&inputs=11&header=&footer=)

Comment: @Razetime oh so there is a shorter way to do that. thanks

Comment: `s` flag should reduce another byte.

Comment: @Razetime guess it's too late to turn back from the flags now, isn't it

Answer (score 2):

### Seriously, 12 bytes

```
,R;Rεj≈@εj≈+
```

[Try it online!](http://seriously.tryitonline.net/#code=LFI7Us61auKJiEDOtWriiYgr&input=Ng)

Explanation:

```
,R;Rεj≈@εj≈+
,R;           push two copies of range(1, input()+1)
   R          reverse one copy
    εj≈@εj≈   concatenate both and cast both to ints
           +  add
```

Answer (score 2):

### PowerShell, 35 bytes

```
param($a)+-join(1..$a)+-join($a..1)
```

Converts the input to ranges with `..`, then `-join`s them together, and adds 'em up.

Will work for input numbers up to `138`, while `139` will give `Infinity`, and `140` and above will barf out an awesomely verbose casting error:

```
Cannot convert value "12345678910111213141516171819202122232425262728293031323334353637383940414243444546474849505152535455565758596061626364656667686970717273
747576777879808182838485868788899091929394959697989910010110210310410510610710810911011111211311411511611711811912012112212312412512612712812913013113213313413
5136137138139140" to type "System.Int32". Error: "Value was either too large or too small for an Int32."
```

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript (ES6), 99

This adds digit by digit, so it can handle numbers well above the 53 bits of precision of javascript

```js
n=>eval("for(a=b=c=r='';n;a+=n--)b=n+b;for(i=a.length;i--;r=c%10+r)c=(c>9)-(-a[i]-b[i]);c>9?1+r:r")
```

**Test**

```js
f=n=>eval("for(a=b=c=r='';n;a+=n--)b=n+b;for(i=a.length;i--;r=c%10+r)c=(c>9)-(-a[i]-b[i]);c>9?1+r:r")

// Less golfed
U=n=>{
  for(a=b=c=r=''; n; --n)
      b=n+b, a+=n;
  for(i=a.length; i--; r = c%10+r) 
      c=(c>9)-(-a[i]-b[i]);
  return c>9? 1+r : r;
}

function test() {
  var n=+I.value
  R.textContent=f(n)
}  

test()
```

```html
N: <input id=I value=11 oninput="test()"> -> <span id=R></span>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for 9. Also, why not initialise `c` with the other variables?

Comment: You have my upvote.

Answer (score 2):

## [MATL](https://esolangs.org/wiki/MATL), 13 bytes

```
:tP2:"wVXvU]+
```

*EDIT (May 20, 2016) The code in the link uses `Xz` instead of `Xv`, owing to recent changes in the language.*

[**Try it online!**](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=OnRQMjoid1ZYelVdKw&input=MTE)

```
:                % range [1,2,...,n], where n is input
 tP              % duplicate and flip
   2:"     ]     % do this twice
      w          % swap
       V         % convert array of numbers to string with numbers and spaces
        Xv       % remove spaces
          U      % convert to number
            +    % add the two numbers
```

Comment: Doesn't work for 11 or 10. (Hint: reverse range before converting to string.)

Comment: @ӍѲꝆΛҐӍΛПҒЦꝆ Thanks! Corrected

Comment: Great! Have an upvote.

Answer (score 2):

## Pyth - 8 bytes

```
siRT_BSQ
```

[Try it online here](https://pyth.herokuapp.com/?code=siRT_BSQ&input=6&debug=0).

Comment: I think this doesn't work for `10` or `11`

Answer (score 2):

## [Brachylog](https://github.com/JCumin/Brachylog), 24 bytes

```
:1fLrcC,Lc+C=.,{,.:1re?}
```

Answer (score 2):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E), 5 bytes

```
LJDR+
```

Explanation:

```
L     # Pushes an array containing 1 .. [implicit] input
 J    # Join the array to a string (eg. [1, 2, 3] -> 123)
  D   # Duplicate the array
   R  # Reverse the duplicate
    + # Add them together
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/05ab1e#@@/j5RKk/f@/2de8fN3kxOSMVAA)

Comment: Late comment, but doesn't work for 10 - you are reversing the string after you join, instead of before.

Answer (score 1):

## R, <s>34</s> <s>60</s> 64 bytes

```
f=pryr::f;g=f(as.numeric(paste(x,collapse='')));f(g(1:n)+g(n:1))
```

Assumes `pryr` package is installed. this gives `f` as a shorthand for creating functions.

Edit added 26 bytes but returns a function that works, not something entirely wrong.

Edit added another 4 bytes to handle cases above n=10 where strtoi (previously used) was returning `NA`

Answer (score 1):

## Bash + coreutils, 39

```
eval echo {1..$1} + {$1..1}|tr -d \ |bc
```

Or:

```
bc<<<`eval printf %s {1..$1} + {$1..1}`
```

[Ideone.](https://ideone.com/r43Gyg)

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 6](http://perl6.org), 25 bytes

```perl6
{([~] @_=1..$^n)+[R~] @_}
```

```perl6
{
  (
    [~]           # reduce with the string concatenation infix op:
    @_ = 1 .. $^n # the range 1 to input ( also stored in @_ )
  )
  +               # add that to
  [R~] @_         # @_ reduced in reverse
}
```

#### Usage:

```perl6
for 6, 11, 12 -> $n {
  say {([~] @_=1..$^n)+[R~] @_}( $n )
}
```

```
777777
2345555545332
244567776755433
```

Comment: I think you can do with `$n` instead of `$^n`

Comment: @dev-null Not if I want it to be an input to the block. the `-> $n {` is a different one to `$^n`.

Answer (score 1):

## [Dyalog APL](http://goo.gl/9KrKoM), 17 bytes

```
+/⍎¨∊¨⍕¨¨x(⌽x←⍳⎕)
```

`⎕` prompt for input
`⍳`' enumerate until input
`x←` store list in x
`⌽` reverse x
`x(`…`)` prepend reversed list with original list
`⍕¨¨` convert each number of each list into character string
`∊¨` make each list of character strings into single character strings
`⍎¨` convert each character string into a number
`+/` sum the two numbers.

Answer (score 1):

### Lua, 53 Bytes

This program takes `n` as a command-line argument.

```lua
s=""r=s for i=1,arg[1]do r,s=i..r,s..i end print(s+r)
```

I assumed that outputing a number with a decimal part of 0 was okay (in the form `777777.0` because this is the default way to output a number in lua (there's no distinction between integer and float)

Comment: Its not the string itself that is reversed, but the digits. Your code fails on n >= 10.

Comment: @Moop Corrected at the price of 1 byte ^^'. Thanks for the comment ^^'

Comment: You can save 3 more using ... instead of arg[1] nice work on the reverse concat for r, didn't think of that in my answer. +1

Comment: @Moop I saw your post, nice use of it, I didn't even know you could use `...` like that! I'll keep it this way for the moment, because I can't use anything else than the online compiler and it can't handle that(I'd like to test it and play with it a little bit before putting it in a answer :))

Answer (score 1):

## Lua, 57

```
a=''b=''for i=1,...do a=a..i b=b.. ...-i+1 end return a+b
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 37 bytes

25 bytes, plus 1 for `-p` and 11 for `-MList::Gen`

```
$_=<[.]1..$_>+<[R.]1..$_>
```

---

Previous solution, 40 bytes: 39, plus one for `-p`

```
@a=reverse@_=1..$_;$"=$\;$_="@a"+"@_"
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 36 bytes

Includes +1 for `-p`

Run with on STDIN

```
perl -p reverse.pl <<< 6
```

`reverse.pl`

```
$_=eval join"",map{abs||"+"}-$_..$_
```

Answer (score 1):

### Haskell, <s>57</s> <s>56</s> 48 bytes

This could probably be golfed a bit more, but here it goes:

```
f x=read y+(read.reverse$y)where y=[1..x]>>=show
```

Edit: shaved off a space before the where.

Answer (score 1):

## [Factor](https://factorcode.org/), 59 bytes

```
[ [1,b] dup reverse [ [ present ] map concat dec> ] bi@ + ]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##PYyxDsIwDER3vuJ2UKWsICE2xMKCmKoMrmugIqSpkyLx9cF0YDu9e3c34jJqvV5O5@MWLyqPRineJeMpGiUgqWSJBVmmWSJbsUiJNIsu@aeU8kk6mLZbOVdbtG7TefRzgspbTIWx/5e3XQKPkamgF94b6YYD1vCVKQQ09Qs)

- `[1,b]` Create a range from 1 to the input, inclusive.
- `dup reverse` Make a copy and reverse it.
- `[ [ present ] map concat dec> ] bi@` Convert them both to numbers of concatenated numbers.
- `+` Add.

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 79 bytes

```python
a=''.join([str(i+1) for i in range(int(input()))])
print(int(a)+(int(a[::-1])))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/7/P9FWXV0vKz8zTyO6uKRII1PbUFMhLb9IIVMhM0@hKDEvPVUjM68EiAtKSzQ0NTVjNbkKiiAiJRqJmtoQOtrKStcwFij9/78ZAA)

Answer (score 1):

## [Thunno 2](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2) `s`, 4 [bytes](https://github.com/Thunno/Thunno2/blob/main/docs/codepage.md)

```
RJNḲ
```

[Try it online!](https://Not-Thonnu.github.io/run#aGVhZGVyPSZjb2RlPVJKTiVFMSVCOCVCMiZmb290ZXI9JmlucHV0PTExJmZsYWdzPXNl)

##### Explanation

```python
RJNḲ  # Implicit input
R     # Push [1..input]
 J    # Join into a string
  N   # Convert to integer
   Ḳ  # Duplicate and reverse
      # Sum the stack
      # Implicit output
```

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 64 bytes

```
Plus@@FromDigits/@#&[""<>ToString/@#&/@{#,Reverse@#}&[Range@#]]&
```

Answer (score 0):

## Retina, 80 bytes (ISO 8859-1 encoding)

```
'+
$0¶$0
+`^(('+)')
$2 $1
+`('('+))$
$1 $2
(')+( |$)?
$#1
(\d+)¶(\d+)
$1$*'$2$*'
```

IO is in unary with `'` as the counting character. In theory supports any integer you throw at it, in practice...online interpreter refuses to process anything larger than 6 (unary `''''''`).

[Try it online!](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=JysKJDDCtiQwCitgXigoJyspJykKJDIgJDEKK2AoJygnKykpJAokMSAkMgooJykrKCB8JCk_CiQjMQooXGQrKcK2KFxkKykKJDEkKickMiQqJw&input=JycnJycn)
[Try it online! (decimal IO - 91 bytes)](http://retina.tryitonline.net/#code=XGQKJDAkKicKJysKJDDCtiQwCitgXigoJyspJykKJDIgJDEKK2AoJygnKykpJAokMSAkMgooJykrKCB8JCk_CiQjMQooXGQrKcK2KFxkKykKJDEkKickMiQqJwon&input=Ng)

Answer (score 0):

## , 12 chars / 15 bytes

```
⨭⟮⩤⁽1ï⟯⨝,Ⅰᴚ⨝
```

<kbd>[Try it here (Firefox only).](http://molarmanful.github.io/ESMin/interpreter3.html?eval=true&input=10&code=%E2%A8%AD%E2%9F%AE%E2%A9%A4%E2%81%BD1%C3%AF%E2%9F%AF%E2%A8%9D%2C%E2%85%A0%E1%B4%9A%E2%A8%9D)</kbd>

Meh.

## Explanation

Takes a range `[1,input]`, joins it; takes that same range, reverses it, then joins it; the sum of both ranges is the result.

Answer (score 0):

## Ruby, 40 characters

```ruby
->n{eval (l=[*1..n])*''+?++l.reverse*''}
```

Sample run:

```
irb(main):001:0> ->n{eval (l=[*1..n])*''+?++l.reverse*''}[11]
=> 2345555545332

irb(main):002:0> ->n{eval (l=[*1..n])*''+?++l.reverse*''}[6]
=> 777777
```

Answer (score 0):

## C#, 126 bytes

```
using System.Linq;a=>{var b=Enumerable.Range(1,a);return long.Parse(string.Concat(b))+long.Parse(string.Concat(b.Reverse()));}
```

Could possibly be golfed further. Not really sure.

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, <s>42</s> 39 characters

```groovy
{[1..it,it..1]*.join()*.toLong().sum()}
```

Sample run:

```
groovy:000> ({[1..it,it..1]*.join()*.toLong().sum()})(11)
===> 2345555545332

groovy:000> ({[1..it,it..1]*.join()*.toLong().sum()})(6)
===> 777777
```

Answer (score 0):

## Groovy, 112 characters

```
def r(n){if(n==1){return n;};return n+''+r(n-1)};n=6;s=r(args[0].toLong());print s.toLong()+s.reverse().toLong()
```

run with:

```
groovy filename.groovy *input*
```

Answer (score 0):

## Perl 6, 25 bytes

Either one works

```perl6
{([~] 1..$^n)+[R~] 1..$n}
{([~] 1..$^n)+[~] $n...1}
```

Answer (score 0):

### [QBIC](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0B0R1Jgqp8Gg4cVJCZkRkdEthZDQ), 24 bytes, nc

```
:[a|B=B+!b$]_FB|?!A!+!B!
```

Explanation

```
:       Read command line argument as 'a'
        Generate the sequence 1 ... a
[a|     For b = 1 to a step 1
B=B+!b$ Add b cast to string to the end of B$ (starts out empty)
]       Ends the FOR loop
_FB|    Reverse (Flip) B$ and assign the result to A$
?       Show on screen
!A!+!B! A$ cast to num + B$ cast to num
```

Non-competing, the `_F` was implemented way after this challenge was posted.

Answer (score 0):

## [Pushy](https://github.com/FTcode/Pushy), 10 bytes

```
RV@KjOjv+#
```

**[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/pushy#@x8U5uCd5Z9Vpq38//9/Q0MA)**

```
RV    \ Push the range to both stacks.
@Kj   \ Reverse and join the first stack
Oj    \ Join the second stack
v+    \ Sum the two resulting integers
#     \ Print result
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 31 bytes

```arturo
$->n[+do join@n..1do join@1..n]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?mdO11W)

```
$->n[          ; a function taking an argument n
    1..n       ; the range [1..n]
    @          ; reify to block of integers
    join       ; convert [1 2 3] to "123", for instance
    do         ; eval -- convert numeric string to integer
    n..1       ; the range [n..1]
    @          ; reify to block of integers
    join       ; convert [1 2 3] to "123", for instance
    do         ; eval -- convert numeric string to integer
    +          ; add
]              ; end function
```